# What is a "callable"?

Tags: python, callable

Now that it's clear [what a metaclass is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python), there is an associated concept that I use all the time without knowing what it really means.

I suppose everybody made once a mistake with parenthesis, resulting  in an "object is not callable" exception. What's more, using `__init__` and `__new__` lead to wonder what this bloody `__call__` can be used for.

Could you give me some explanations, including examples with the magic method ?

Comment: related: [Python internals: how callables work](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/03/23/python-internals-how-callables-work/)

Answer (score 360, accepted):

A callable is anything that can be called.

The [built-in *callable* (PyCallable_Check in objects.c)](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/object.c) checks if the argument is either:

- an instance of a class with a `__call__` method or
- is of a type that has a non null *tp_call* (c struct) member which indicates callability otherwise (such as in functions, methods etc.)

The method named `__call__` is ([according to the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__))

> Called when the instance is ''called'' as a function

### Example

```
class Foo:
  def __call__(self):
    print 'called'

foo_instance = Foo()
foo_instance() #this is calling the __call__ method
```

Comment: Note that the builtin callable is being removed in Python 3.0 in favor of checking for __call__

Comment: @Eli: Hmm that sounds like a **very** bad move. `callable` actually tells you if something is callable or not, while checking for `__call__` tells you nothing; If an object `o` provides `__getattribute__` or `__getattr__`, `hasattr(o, '__call__')` may return True, yet `o` will still not be callable because Python skips `__getattribute__` and `__getattr__` for calls. The only real way left to check if something is callable is thus EAFP.

Comment: @Longpoke: Just for the record, please see [the documentation for `callable()` in Python 3.x](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#callable): "_This function was first removed in Python 3.0 and then brought back in Python 3.2._".

Comment: It seems in python 3.8 only the presence of `tp_call` is checked. See implementation of [PyCallable_Check](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/object.c#L1432), it's 3 lines.

Comment: @MichelePiccolini It's been that way for over a decade actually, but it still works to do what it's documented to do, which is to check if something is callable or not. When Python 3 was still young they changed the implementation, and now objects with a `__call__` method just always have `tp_call` set as well. I'm not sure when "all callables have `tp_call`" was implemented, but the `PyCallable_Check` change happened in back in August *2006*: https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/50e9fb9e2d6b4b12524116ab775ac6543e4a5332#diff-ba56d44ce0dd731d979970b966fde9d8dd15d12a82f727a052a8ad48d4a49363

Comment: To be precise, the old `PyCallable_Check` implemented did **_not_** check if something was "an instance of a class with a `__call__` method"! It did a `PyInstance_Check`, which is *different* in that it only detects for *old-style* classes. I think new-style classes always had the `tp_call` attribute if they were callable. I'm gonna suggest an edit to the answer to clear this up.

Comment: Okay, well, the edit queue is full. But if it were me, I would have 1: reversed the order of the two list items; 2: either deleted the parenthetical "(such as in functions, methods etc)" or added ", new-style classes with `__call__`" to that parenthetical; and 3: reworded the other item to say "(only in Python 2) an instance of an old-style class with a `__call__` method). Because the `tp_call` check covers *everything in Python 3 and everything except old-style classes in Python 2*, and so the `tp_call` check is the overwhelmingly common and most relevant case.

Comment: Regardless of what the C implementation checks, it's worth noting that in modern Python, functions *do have a `__call__` attribute*, which is defined to be a `method-wrapper` instance that represents the function. Given `def x(): pass`, we have the invariant that `x.__call__.__self__ is x`.

Answer (score 92):

From Python's sources [object.c](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Objects/object.c?rev=64962&view=markup):

```c
/* Test whether an object can be called */

int
PyCallable_Check(PyObject *x)
{
    if (x == NULL)
        return 0;
    if (PyInstance_Check(x)) {
        PyObject *call = PyObject_GetAttrString(x, "__call__");
        if (call == NULL) {
            PyErr_Clear();
            return 0;
        }
        /* Could test recursively but don't, for fear of endless
           recursion if some joker sets self.__call__ = self */
        Py_DECREF(call);
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return x->ob_type->tp_call != NULL;
    }
}
```

It says:

1. If an object is an instance of some class then it is callable *iff* it has `__call__` attribute.
2. Else the object `x` is callable *iff* `x->ob_type->tp_call != NULL`

Desciption of [`tp_call` field](http://docs.python.org/api/type-structs.html):

> `ternaryfunc tp_call` An optional
>   pointer to a function that implements
>   calling the object. This should be
>   NULL if the object is not callable.
>   The signature is the same as for
>   PyObject_Call(). This field is
>   inherited by subtypes.

You can always use built-in `callable` function to determine whether given object is callable or not; or better yet just call it and catch `TypeError` later. `callable` is removed in Python 3.0 and 3.1, use `callable = lambda o: hasattr(o, '__call__')` or `isinstance(o, collections.Callable)`.

Example, a simplistic cache implementation:

```
class Cached:
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.function = function
        self.cache = {}

    def __call__(self, *args):
        try: return self.cache[args]
        except KeyError:
            ret = self.cache[args] = self.function(*args)
            return ret
```

Usage:

```
@Cached
def ack(x, y):
    return ack(x-1, ack(x, y-1)) if x*y else (x + y + 1)
```

Example from standard library, file [`site.py`](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/site.py), definition of built-in `exit()` and `quit()` functions:

```
class Quitter(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Use %s() or %s to exit' % (self.name, eof)
    def __call__(self, code=None):
        # Shells like IDLE catch the SystemExit, but listen when their
        # stdin wrapper is closed.
        try:
            sys.stdin.close()
        except:
            pass
        raise SystemExit(code)
__builtin__.quit = Quitter('quit')
__builtin__.exit = Quitter('exit')
```

Comment: I find the example for the __call__ method highly missleading because it mixes it with a recipe for caching and decorators, which add nothing to the understanding of __call__

Comment: @Florian Bösch: It is a real-world example (I've just copy-pasted that code snippet, I didn't write it for the answer). I'm sorry you find it  misleading.

Comment: J.F. Sebastian, an example is good if you can take nothing away anymore without breaking it. Direct your gaze a bit below to my answer to see an example that demonstrates nothing but __call__.

Comment: J.F. Sebastian, also piling more examples you copy&pasted from somewhere else that are not minimal doesn't help.

Comment: @Florian Bösch: Real working code is better then artificial examples. Good programming books contain practical examples: K&R "The C Programming Language",  "The UNIX Programming Environment", GoF "Design Patterns", esr "The Art of Unix Programming", etc.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: It's BS that more life-like examples are better. I could show you life-like code that would make you weep as an example. Simple examples work too, and they work better to illustrate something because they don't distract.

Comment: You are explaining what's a callable, but you gave an example how to use callable objects to define a decorator. I know it's a typical usage of __callable__ but this can confuse readers who just want to know what is callable and how to use __callable__. I'd prefer @Florian Bösch's answer.

Comment: @Kay: I also like the @Florian Bösch's answer (in its current form). btw, a decorator is *not* a typical usage of a "callable". The most typical "callables" are functions/methods such as `def f(): ...`, and class objects such as `class C: ...` i.e., `f`, `''.strip`, `len`, and `C` all are callable. Instances that have a `__call__()` method in their class are relatively rare.

Comment: What does this mean ```ret = self.cache[args] = self.function(*args)```. I can't wrap my mind around this idea of using *=* more than once in an expression.

Comment: @maddypie: it just means that both `ret` and `self.cache[args]` refer to the result of the `self.function(*args)` call. To make sure you understand, try to deduce what is `d` in the statement: `d, k = d[k] = {}, 'a'` (it is just an exercise, don't use such constructions in prod.code) -- hint: the value on the right is evaluated first, the assignment happens left to right.

Comment: @jfs: you explained precisly. If I am correct,  ```d``` here is first assigned to ```{}```.  But then ```d``` is made into a ```dict```, ```d={'a': ({}, 'a')}```.

Comment: @jfs: this is mysterious. ```d``` returned an infinitely nested dictionary!

Comment: @maddypie to solve the mystery, it is enough to count how many dictionaries objects are created in the statement—exactly *one* (`{}` literal creates it) i.e., `d` is self-referential: `d = {k: (d, k)}` (note: `d` is not an empty dictionary at this point)

Answer (score 46):

A callable is an object allows you to use round parenthesis ( ) and eventually pass some parameters, just like functions.

Every time you define a function python creates a callable object. 
In example, you could define the function **func** in these ways (it's the same):

```
class a(object):
    def __call__(self, *args):
        print 'Hello'

func = a()

# or ... 
def func(*args):
    print 'Hello'
```

You could use this method instead of methods like **doit** or **run**, I think it's just more clear to see obj() than obj.doit()

Answer (score 42):

Let me explain backwards:

Consider this...

```
foo()
```

... as syntactic sugar for:

```
foo.__call__()
```

Where `foo` can be any object that responds to `__call__`. When I say any object, I mean it: built-in types, your own classes and their instances.

In the case of built-in types, when you write:

```
int('10')
unicode(10)
```

You're essentially doing:

```
int.__call__('10')
unicode.__call__(10)
```

That's also why you don't have `foo = new int` in Python: you just make the class object return an instance of it on `__call__`. The way Python solves this is very elegant in my opinion.

Comment: You're essentially doing `type(int).__call__(int, '10')` and `type(unicode).__call__(unicode, '10')`. Dunders are always called on their class, not through the instance. And they never go through the metaclass either. For most cases that's just a nitpick, but it matters sometimes.

Comment: Built-in types work in special ways in the reference C implementation, although what happens is essentially equivalent to this, yes. For user-defined types, writing `MyClass()` attempts to call the class, by looking for a `__call__` method on `MyClass` **'s class**, i.e. it skips doing attribute lookup within `MyClass` (otherwise it could find a user-defined `__call__` intended for the instances!) and finds `type.__call__` - which then evaluates to a bound method on `MyClass` via the usual mechanisms, which is then called.

Answer (score 11):

A Callable is an object that has the `__call__` method.  This means you can fake callable functions or do neat things like [Partial Function Application](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0309/) where you take a function and add something that enhances it or fills in some of the parameters, returning something that can be called in turn (known as [Currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) in functional programming circles).

Certain typographic errors will have the interpreter attempting to call something you did not intend, such as (for example) a string.  This can produce errors where the interpreter attempts to execute a non-callable application.  You can see this happening in a python interpreter by doing something like the transcript below.

```
[nigel@k9 ~]$ python
Python 2.5 (r25:51908, Nov  6 2007, 15:55:44) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20070925 (Red Hat 4.1.2-27)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 'aaa'()    # <== Here we attempt to call a string.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
>>>
```

Answer (score 11):

`__call__` makes any object be callable as a function.

This example will output 8:

```
class Adder(object):
  def __init__(self, val):
    self.val = val

  def __call__(self, val):
    return self.val + val

func = Adder(5)
print func(3)
```

Answer (score 7):

Quite simply, a "callable" is something that can be called like a method.  The built in function "callable()" will tell you whether something appears to be callable, as will checking for a **call** property.  Functions are callable as are classes, class instances can be callable.  See more about this [here](http://docs.python.org/lib/built-in-funcs.html) and [here](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/callable-python-objects).

Comment: To warp the readers' mind a bit: classes are callable because *they are instances of* a class that has callable instances. You may have heard of it: it's called `type`. This object, uniquely, is its own type, and an instance of itself. It defines a `__call__` method so that classes can be callable; that's where the implementation-specific magic is invoked to actually allocate memory, as well as potentially using the class' `__new__` hook and then calling `__init__` on the resultant object.

Answer (score 6):

In Python a callable is an object which type has a `__call__` method:

```
>>> class Foo:
...  pass
... 
>>> class Bar(object):
...  pass
... 
>>> type(Foo).__call__(Foo)
<__main__.Foo instance at 0x711440>
>>> type(Bar).__call__(Bar)
<__main__.Bar object at 0x712110>
>>> def foo(bar):
...  return bar
... 
>>> type(foo).__call__(foo, 42)
42
```

As simple as that :)

This of course can be overloaded:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...  def __call__(self):
...   return 42
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f()
42
```

Answer (score 4):

It's something you can put "(args)" after and expect it to work.  A callable is usually a method or a class.  Methods get called, classes get instantiated.

Answer (score 3):

To check function or method of class is callable or not that means we can call that function.

```
Class A:
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.val = val
    def bar(self):
        print "bar"

obj = A()      
callable(obj.bar)
True
callable(obj.__init___)
False
def foo(): return "s"
callable(foo)
True
callable(foo())
False
```

Comment: Are you sure `callable(obj.__init___)` doesn't have an extra underscore (as in AttributeError)? If it doesn't, are you sure the answer isn't `True` for that one?

Answer (score 2):

callables implement the `__call__` special method so any object with such a method is callable.

Comment: An instance on which you define `__call__` won't be callable if the class doesn't define such a method.

Answer (score 0):

Callable is a type or class of "Build-in function or Method" with a method
**call**

```
>>> type(callable)
<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
>>>
```

Example:
**print** is a callable object. With a build-in function ****call****
When you invoke the **print** function, Python creates an **object of type print** and invokes its method ****call**** passing the parameters if any.

```
>>> type(print)
<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
>>> print.__call__(10)
10
>>> print(10)
10
>>>
```

Comment: Some of the info here is straight up wrong. E.g. "When you invoke the `print` function, Python creates an object of type print and invokes its method `__call__`". Python does not create a print object. It just calls something equivalent to `type(print).__call__(print, *args, **kwargs)`. And the first sentence doesn't make much sense. You appear to be confusing a callable object and "callable" the function.

Answer (score 0):

A class, function, method and object which has `__call__()` are **callable**.

You can check if callable with [**callable()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#callable) which returns `True` if callable and returns `False` if not callable as shown below:

```py
class Class1:
    def __call__(self):
        print("__call__")

class Class2:
    pass

def func():
    pass

print(callable(Class1))   # Class1
print(callable(Class2))   # Class2

print(callable(Class1())) # Class1 object
print(callable(Class2())) # Class2 object

print(callable(func))     # func
```

Then, only **`Class2` object** which doesn't have `__call__()` is not callable returning `False` as shown below:

```
True  # Class1
True  # Class2
True  # Class1 object
False # Class2 object
True  # func
```

In addition, all of them below are not callable returning `False` as shown below:

```py
print(callable("Hello"))  # "str" type
print(callable(100))      # "int" type
print(callable(100.23))   # "float" type
print(callable(100 + 2j)) # "complex" type
print(callable(True))     # "bool" type
print(callable(None))     # "NoneType"
print(callable([]))       # "list" type
print(callable(()))       # "tuple" type
print(callable({}))       # "dict" type
print(callable({""}))     # "set" type
```

Output:

```
False # "str" type
False # "int" type
False # "float" type
False # "complex" type
False # "bool" type
False # "NoneType"
False # "list" type
False # "tuple" type
False # "dict" type
False # "set" type
```