# Why do we have callable objects in python?

Tags: python, callable

What is the purpose of a callable object? What problems do they solve?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They take parameters and return a result depending on those parameters.

A *callable* is just an abstract form of a function resp an interface that defines that an object acts like a function (i.e. accepts parameters).

As functions are first class objects, it is obvious that functions are callable objects. If you are talking about the `__call__` method, this is just one of the many special methods with which you can overload the behavior of custom objects, e.g. for arithmetic operations or also defining what happens if you *call* an object.

One idea why to use such is to have some kind of factory object that itself creates other objects.

Comment: +1 : see related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234/what-is-a-callable-in-python

Answer (score 13):

Many kinds of objects are callable in Python, and they can serve many purposes:

- functions are callable, and they may carry along a "closure" from an outer function
- classes are callable, and calling a class gets you an instance of that class
- methods are callable, for function-like behavior specifically pertaining to an instance
- staticmethods and classmethods are callable, for method-like functionality when the
  functionality pertains to "a whole class" in some sense (staticmethods' usefulness is
  dubious, since a classmethod could do just as well;-)
- generators are callable, and calling a generator gets you an iterator object
- finally, and this may be specifically what you were asking about (not realizing that
  all of the above are objects too...!!!), you can code a class whose *instances* are
  callable: this is often the simplest way to have calls that update an instance's
  state as well as depend on it (though a function with a suitable closure, and a bound
  method, offer alternatives, a callable instance is the one way to go when you need to
  perform both calling **and** some other specific operation on the same object: for
  example, an object you want to be able to call but also apply indexing to had better
  be an instance of a class that's both callable and indexable;-).

A great range of examples of the kind of "problems they solve" is offered by Python's standard library, which has many cases of each of the specific types I mention above.

Comment: What do you mean with "closure"?

Comment: Addition: I did not know that everything in pyhon is an object. Thought this was a just a java thing. Having callable objects is like having an unnamed function. How can this be useful in any case? I stumbled over this python feature in the hugging face pipeline object. I found it very opaque what pipeline('abc') would even do. I learnd it just "runs" the pipeline with a given input. However, they could have just implemented a function "run()", "forward()" etc. I dont see that callable-objects are useful in the context of clean code

Answer (score 2):

There are areas, especially in the 'functions calling functions of function functions' where objects allow less nesting.

Consider making a classic decorator that checks an authorization level before calling a function.  Using it is clear:

```
@check_authorization(level="Manager")
def update_price(Item, new_price):...
```

You could do this as nested functions:

```
def check_authorization(level):
     def take_params(function):
         def concrete(*args, **kwargs):
             if user_level_greater_than(level):
                 return function(*args, 
                     **kwargs)
             return None
         return concrete
     return take_params
```

Or you could to this as a class, which might be clearer:

```
  class check_authorization(object):
      def __init__(level):
         self.level = level
      def __call__(function):
          self.function = function
          return self.dec
      def dec(self, *args, **kwargs):
          if user_level_greater_than(self.level):
             return self.function(*args,v**kwargs)
          return None
```

Many would find this flat method more clear. Of course, I believe in cheating, because I like the signatures and metadata correct:

```
from dectools.dectools import make_call_if

@make_call_if
def check_authorization(function, arg, kwargs, level):
    return user_level_greater_than(level)
```

The callable object is a tool which is good for some known applications and may also be good for the bizarre problem real life throws at you.