# SQLAlchemy: 'Model' object is not callable

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using Flask framework with sqlalchemy and I can't query some related table of a result.

Users > have many > orders

So I have the order and I want to query the user that order belongs to.

```
order = Order.query.get( id )
return order.user()
```

When I call this I get that the 'User' object is not callable. Here's how my relation is defined:

```
#   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#   MODELS
#   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class User( object ):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    query = db_session.query_property()

class Order( object ):
    __tablename__ = 'order'

    query = db_session.query_property()

#   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#   MODELS SCHEMA
#   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
users_table = Table( 'user', metadata,
    Column( 'id', Integer, primary_key = True ),
    Column( 'username', String( 50 ), unique = True ),
    Column( 'email', String( 50 ), unique = True ),
    Column( 'password', String( 32 ), nullable = False ),
    ...
    mysql_engine = 'InnoDB',
    mysql_charset = 'utf8'
 )

orders_table = Table( 'order', metadata,
    Column( 'id', Integer, primary_key = True ),
    Column( 'user_id', Integer, ForeignKey( 'user.id' ) ),
    Column( 'transaction_id', String( 32 ), unique = True ),
    ...
    mysql_engine = 'InnoDB',
    mysql_charset = 'utf8'
 )

#   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#   MAPPERS
#   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mapper( User, users_table, properties = {
    #   has many
    'orders' : relationship( Order )
} )

mapper( Order, orders_table, properties = {
    #   belongs to
    'user': relationship( User )
} )
```

Any idea why this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`order` is the order object, and you've defined the "user" relationship as a property. Therefore, the property "user" will represent the user object. This may be unlike other ORMs you've used where `order.user` is actually some function that needs to get called to retrieve the user, or perhaps a query object that returns the user.

Do the following if you'd like to see this in action...

```
user = order.user
print type(user)
```

You'll notice that `order.user` returns a "User" instance (or in some cases may return `None` or raise an exception). In this case, calling `order.user()` will try to "call" the `User` instance.

The error message therefore makes sense, since you're trying to call a `User` instance, and `User` hasn't been defined as a [callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436578/why-do-we-have-callable-objects-in-python) object.

Comment: So you probably want "user.username", not "user()"

Comment: Right, so getting the username is "order.user.username", not "order.user().username"