# Is a generator the callable? Which is the generator?

Tags: python, generator, callable

> A generator  is simply a function which returns an object on which you can call next, such that for every call it returns some value, until it raises a StopIteration exception, signaling that all values have been generated. Such an object is called an iterator.

```
>>> def myGen(n):
...     yield n
...     yield n + 1
... 
>>> g = myGen(6)
```

I quoted this from [Understanding Generators in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1756156/2961429)

Here is what I am trying to figure out:

1. Which is the generator? `myGen` or `myGen(6)`?

   According to the quote mentioned above, I think the generator should be `myGen`. And `myGen(6)` is the returned iterator object. But I am really not sure about it.
2. When I tried this:

   ```
   >>> type(myGen)
   <type 'function'>
   >>> type(g)         # <1>this is confusing me.
   <type 'generator'>  
   >>> callable(g)     # <2> g is not callable.  
   False               
   >>> callable(myGen)
   True
   >>> g is iter(g)    # <3> so g should an iterable and an iterator 
   True                # at the same time. And it will be passed as an argument
   >>> for i in g:     # to built-in function `next()` in a "for...in..." loop.
           print i     # (is that correct?)

   6
   7
   ```

So, according to `<1>` and `<2>`, `g`'s type is 'generator' and it is not callable.
But [*generators are callable, and calling a generator gets you an iterator object*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2436614/2961429)
What's going on here?

When I was searching for answers, I run into [*Every time you define a function python creates a callable object.*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/139469/2961429)

So, can I say something like this? *when the function `myGen` is defined, `myGen` is a name referring to a callable object which is an instance of a class that has a `__call__` method*. 
In this case, `myGen` is a generator, and `myGen(6)` is the returned iterator when `myGen` is called.

But why does `type(g)` return `<type 'generator'>` at all?
And this returned `iterator` thing also looks suspicious to me since there is no `return` statement in the function.

Isn't it that [*Functions always return something (at least `None`, when no return-statement was reached during execution and the end of the function is reached)*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10067021/2961429)?

Comment: +1 for being well written.

Comment: I believe that a generator is a function that creates an object.  That object is the generator, this generator is an iterable.  But you can call the function that generates an interable on the fly which you can iterate it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The terminology is unfortunately confusing, as "generator" is so commonly used to refer to either the function or the returned iterator that it's hard to say one usage is more correct. The [documentation of the yield statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-yield-statement) says

> The yield statement is only used when defining a **generator function**,
>   and is only used in the body of the generator function. Using a yield
>   statement in a function definition is sufficient to cause that
>   definition to create a generator function instead of a normal
>   function.
>
> When a generator function is called, it returns an iterator known as a
>   **generator iterator**, or more commonly, a **generator**.

The [original PEP introducing the concept](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/) says

> Note that when the intent is clear from context, the unqualified name
>   "generator" may be used to refer **either to a generator-function or a
>   generator-iterator**.

If you want to make a clear distinction, use "generator function" for the function and "generator iterator" for the iterator.

Answer (score 1):

1) `myGen` is function which when invoked returns a generator object - so yes, `myGen(6)` is a generator object.

2) Generators supply `__iter__` and `next()`: [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#generator-types)

Comment: Hm.. I'm still a bit confused why alex said generators are callable. Any explanation?