# Why does iter(v,w) return a class when the callable is a generator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

Consider the following minimum working example:

```
import itertools

for i in iter(itertools.count, 10):
    print(i)
```

I have expected that the output counts to 10. However, the output was `count(0)` over and over again. Printing the type instead gives `<class 'itertools.count'>`.

The documentation of [`iter(object, sentinel)`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#iter) says the following:

> The iterator created in this case will call *object* with no arguments for each call to its `__next__()` method; if the value returned is equal to *sentinel*, `StopIteration` will be raised, otherwise the value will be returned.

Which reads to me like the behaviour I have expected. What have I overlooked? Optional bonus question: How is it possible with `iter` to make *object* a generator and get the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fleshing out the docs for 2-arg iter, it works like:

```
def two_arg_iter(object, sentinel):
    while True:
        temp = object()
        if temp == sentinel:
            break
        yield temp
```

Which does exactly what you see it doing in the case you gave.  Note:

```
>>> itertools.count()
count(0)
```

and `count(0)` is never equal to 10 so you keep getting `count(0)` forever.

It's not clear to me what you're asking, though. Either of these, I believe, would do what you actually want:

```
for i in itertools.count(10):
```

or, redundantly,

```
for i in iter(itertools.count(10)):
```

It may help to realize that 2-arg iter is a very different beast than 1-arg iter.

Comment: Great explanation. TIL the 2-arg iter. Not sure this is what he wants: - break after print ten?  for i in count(0):
 print(i);
 if i == 10: break;

Comment: @DanielHao Yeah, "counts to 10" sounds to me like they meant `iter(itertools.count().__next__, 10)`.

Comment: Wow!  Did not know I've bumped into an expert by Christmas night... are you the Timsort hybrid sorting designer?....

Comment: Together with an [answer of a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21982504), it seems that I have confused *generator functions* with *generator iterators*, and overlooked where exactly the `__next__()` method is called. Thanks for the detailed answer! As to why: I wanted to iterate through a generator without resorting to a `break`. Using `two_arg_iter()` seemed more pythonic, because it was even suggested in the docs for this case. Now that I would have to pass the `__next__()` method (thanks @KellyBundy), it seems more like a hacky workaround.

Comment: In that case, a variant of `itertools.takewhile(lambda i: i != 10, itertools.count())` may sufficiently hide the hacky part ;-)