# How to test that a function is called within a function with nosetests

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, nosetests

I'm trying to set up some automatic unit testing for a project. I have some functions which, as a side effect occasionally call another function. I want to write a unit test which tests that the second function gets called but I'm stumped. Below is pseudocode example:

```
def a(self):
    data = self.get()
    if len(data) > 3500:
        self.b()

    # Bunch of other magic, which is easy to test.

def b(self):
    serial.write("\x00\x01\x02")
```

How do I test that `b()`-gets called?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can mock the function `b` using [mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) module and check if it was called. Here's an example:

```
import unittest
from mock import patch


def a(n):
    if n > 10:
        b()

def b():
    print "test"


class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('__main__.b')
    def test_b_called(self, mock):
        a(11)
        self.assertTrue(mock.called)

    @patch('__main__.b')
    def test_b_not_called(self, mock):
        a(10)
        self.assertFalse(mock.called)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Also see:

- [Assert that a method was called in a Python unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829742/assert-that-a-method-was-called-in-a-python-unit-test)
- [Mocking a class: Mock() or patch()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180769/mocking-a-class-mock-or-patch)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Indeed, if `b` is writing stuff to the serial port, I'd say that you *must* mock it in a unit test.

Comment: Thank you, this is *precisely* what I need to do.

Comment: The order of a, and b seems to matter here. If you switch their order, the tests fail.

Comment: Fantastic answer, simple and easy to understand for a topic I found confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Various solutions are possible for this thing.  But first, I have to point out that unit testing is meant for testing units; what a unit is can be a matter of viewing things.  In your case I'd say a unit is the function `a()` because you would like to test that your unit behaves correctly, meaning it calls function `b()` at the right spot.  A different view would be to say that functions `a()` and `b()` are a unit.  Then you do *not* like to check whether function `b()` gets called, you just want to test the result of the call of function `a()`.  So make up your mind which suits your case best.

In case you really want to test function `a()` as a unit, you should *prepare* your unit to being tested.  In your case that could be done by adding to it an additional argument (which defaults to function `b`) and which will be used instead of the hard-coded function `b()` call in `a()`:

```
def a(self, subfunction=None):
    is subfunction is None:  # for testing
        subfunction = self.b
    data = self.get()
    if len(data) > 3500:
        subfunction()
```

Now you can inject (during testing) a helper function which just informs the test that it got called:

```
store = None
def injected(*args, **kwargs):
    global store
    store = args, kwargs

obj.a(subfunction=injected)
# now check if global store is set properly
```