# Asserting input was not called

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, input, mocking

I've come across a niche situation while writing unit tests in python. I want to assert that the user was **not** prompted for input. There are plenty of examples showing how to [simulate input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21046717/python-mocking-raw-input-in-unittests) using `unittest.mock`, or how to tell if methods of a [user-defined object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829742/assert-that-a-method-was-called-in-a-python-unit-test) were called. However, `input` is a python builtin method.

What would be the best way of doing this?

Comment: Please leave a comment when downvoting so that I can improve my questions in the future

Answer (score 0):

By brute force testing, it looks like the following works:

```py
def foo():
    return 7

with patch('builtins.input', return_value='y') as mocked:
    foo()

mocked.assert_not_called()
```

whereas the following will fail the test:

```py
def foo():
    input('bar')
    return 7

with patch('builtins.input', return_value='y') as mocked:
    foo()

mocked.assert_not_called()
```