# Reading table into pandas using sqlalchemy from SQL Server

Tags: python, pandas, sql-server-2012, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I've been at this for many hours, and cannot figure out what's wrong with my approach.  I'm trying to read a table into pandas using sqlalchemy (from a SQL server 2012 instance) and getting the following error:

`DBAPIError: (Error) ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)") None None`

I'm using the following code:

```
import sqlalchemy as sql

from sqlalchemy import create_engine

import pyodbc

pyodbc.connect('DSN=MYDSN;UID=User;PWD=Password')
```

Which returns:

```
<pyodbc.Connection at 0x10a26a420>
```

Which I think is good.  Then when I run the following:

```
connectionString = 'mssql+pyodbc://User:Password@IPAdress/Database'
engine = sql.create_engine(connectionString)

pd.read_sql("ecodata", engine)
```

I get the following error mentioned above.

Is there something wrong with my driver setup?  I've been wrestling with the driver setup for days and thought I had it beat.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: See here http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/dialects/mssql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.pyodbc for the docs on connecting to sql server with sqlalchemy. Seems you should be able to do something like `create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://User:Password@MYDSN")`.

Comment: But from the error message it seems there is something wrong with your driver. Do you know which driver you use? (on what platform are you?)

Comment: I'm on OSX, believe I'm using unixODBC.  Is there a way to check that, either from terminal or in python?

Comment: Ok, I just tried using the create_engine info you suggested, and I think I'm past that error!  (and that's a big deal!)  It looks like I'm not referencing the database and table correctly, now.  Should that be after the MYDSN?  Like this: `create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://User:Password@MYDSN/Database")`

Comment: What you need to know is what driver you have installed that unixODBC uses to connect with SQL Server (eg FreeTDS)

Comment: It is definitely FreeTDS.  Edit: Using version 8.0

Comment: See the last example in the list here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/dialects/mssql.html#additional-connection-examples to specify a specific driver in sqlalchemy. Something like `create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://User:Password@host/db?driver=FreeTDS")`

Comment: See maybe also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493614/sqlalchemy-equivalent-of-pyodbc-connect-string-using-freetds

Comment: Hey, that did it!!!  Thanks so much for the help!  For the record, here's the syntax that worked: `connectionString = 'mssql+pyodbc://[User]:[Password]@[IPAddress]:[Port]/[Database]?driver=FreeTDS'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the record, the answer to my question was figured out by joris:

My syntax for the connection string was wrong, and when I changed it from this

```
connectionString = 'mssql+pyodbc://User:Password@IPAdress/Database'
```

to this

```
connectionString = 'mssql+pyodbc://User:Password@IPAddress:Port/Database?driver=FreeTDS'
```

It worked!

Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try forming your connection like this. You need a few more parameters.

```
con = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={FreeTDS};SERVER="yourserver";PORT=1433;DATABASE=yourdb;UID=youruser;PWD=yourpassword;TDS_Version=7.2;')
```

To figure out which TDS Version to use:

http://www.freetds.org/userguide/choosingtdsprotocol.htm

Hopefully, this helps!

Comment: The thing is, the OP wants to use pandas `read_sql`, and for this an sqlalchemy engine is needed.