# Sqlalchemy pyodbc DNS-less URL connection string does not seem to work

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sap-ase, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to a Sybase ASE 15 database on windows using sqlalchemy (1.0.9) and pyodbc.  If I use a DNS url everything works as expected:

```
url = r'sybase+pyodbc://usename:password@dns'
engine = create_engine(url, echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
sess = Session()
conn = sess.connection()
```

However, if I avoid the DNS I get an error message:

```
url = 'sybase+pyodbc://username:password@host:port/database?driver=Adaptive Server Enterprise'
```

, I get an error:

> DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('01S00', '[01S00] [SAP][ASE ODBC
>   Driver]Invalid port number (30011) (SQLDriverConnect)')

The port number is correct and it is the same port as specified in the DNS.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be worth trying to work with some version of the semicolon-separated DSN-less format used by pyODBC (and ODBC in general). Some examples here:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/adaptive-server-enterprise-odbc-driver/

This question tackles a similar issue with FreeTDS, but the concept is the same, as the connect string is basically passed through to the low-level ODBC connect:

[SqlAlchemy equivalent of pyodbc connect string using FreeTDS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493614/sqlalchemy-equivalent-of-pyodbc-connect-string-using-freetds)

The URL is being parsed down to this type of string for ultimate connection by pyodbc through to SQLDriverConnect (in the ODBC API), so specifying the ASE ODBC DSN-less connection string directly may work better.

**Update:** Ran a quick test to see what connect arguments are produced for this URL:

```
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import *
from sqlalchemy.connectors.pyodbc import *

connector =  PyODBCConnector()
url = make_url("sybase+pyodbc://username:password@host:5555/database?driver=Adaptive Server Enterprise")
print connector.create_connect_args(url)
```

This results in:

```
[['DRIVER={Adaptive Server Enterprise};Server=host,5555;Database=database;UID=username;PWD=password'], {}]
```

Note that the hostname and port are separated by a comma, per http://www.connectionstrings.com/adaptive-server-enterprise-odbc-driver/tds-based-odbc-driver-from-sybase-ocs-125/, this format works for TDS-based ODBC for Sybase 12.5:

> ```
> Driver={Sybase ASE ODBC Driver};NetworkAddress=myServerAddress,5000;
> Db=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
> ```

However, the ASE 15 format (http://www.connectionstrings.com/adaptive-server-enterprise-odbc-driver/adaptive-server-enterprise-150/) specifies `server=myServerAddress;port=myPortnumber` with `port` as a key passed in the semicolon-delimited string:

> ```
> Driver={Adaptive Server Enterprise};app=myAppName;server=myServerAddress;
> port=myPortnumber;db=myDataBase;uid=myUsername;pwd=myPassword;
> ```

If you "cheat" on the port spec by using `host;port=5555`, you get:

```
[['DRIVER={Adaptive Server Enterprise};Server=host;port=5555;Database=database;UID=username;PWD=password'], {}]
```

But this just feels like a Bad Idea™, even if it works. I'd also note that the generated string is using `Database` as the key vs. `Db` in the Sybase connection string reference. This may prove to be an issue as well.

Using `?odbc_connect` as in the linked question is probably your best option for controlling the exact connect arguments being sent to ODBC.

Comment: Thanks @will.  Going to take more detailed look/test later this afternoon.  A little annoying as not so clean and code becomes less generic. With special handling for Sybase. What do you think of Creator method suggested in the question you attached?

Comment: Will use the first method you suggest (the Bad Idea!).  The second did not appear to work.  I could do also remove port from the string and do the following: connect_args = {'port': port}
engine = create_engine(url, echo=False, connect_args=connect_args)

Comment: That seems reasonable.