# How do I use SQLAlchemy create_engine() with password that includes an @

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

This works:

```
db = pyodbc.connect('driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0}; server=172.30.0.194; database=db;uid=someuser; pwd=fancy@password')
```

This doesn't

```
cn_string = "mssql+pyodbc://someuser:&quot;fancy&amp;password&quot;@172.30.0.194/db?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0"
return create_engine(cn_string)
```

This doesn't either:

```
driver = "SQL Server Native Client 11.0"
server = "192.30.0.194"
database = "EPM_Dashboard"
uid = "someuser"
pwd = "fancy@password"
params = f'DRIVER={{{driver}}};SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={uid};PWD={{{pwd}}};'

connection_string = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s' % urllib.parse.quote_plus(params)

return create_engine(connection_string)
```

I get something like:

Login timeout expired (0); [08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. (53)

which would be more believable if the pyodbc item failed.

Here's another failure:

```
return create_engine(urllib.parse.quote_plus('driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0}; server=172.30.0.194; database=EPM_Dashboard;uid=someuser; pwd=fancy@password'))
```

I'm sure there's a tricky character somewhere I'm missing.

Here are some resources

https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-databases

[Special character in SQL password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61431480/special-character-in-sql-password)

[SqlAlchemy equivalent of pyodbc connect string using FreeTDS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493614/sqlalchemy-equivalent-of-pyodbc-connect-string-using-freetds)

Comment: That's not an authentication error, it's a timeout. Check the firewall is open, SQL Server is enabled for remote connection and TCP listening is enabled

Comment: The reason why I think all of that is fine is because on the same computer the pyodbc works.  It's just the sqlalchemy create_engine  that isn't working

Comment: What does `urllib.parse.quote_plus` do, is that the correct method for creating a connection string for sqlalchemy? (No idea, never used it myself)

Comment: I imagine it puts in html entities or something. This is what the first link used.  I figured its the same encoding.  Looks like sa may have their own different encoder?  All these languages, This is why we need a monopoly in software

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you need to construct a connection URL that may have "funny characters" in it then you can use [URL.create()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.engine.URL.create) to build it for you:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

connection_url = sa.URL.create(
    "mssql+pyodbc",
    username="someuser",
    password="fancy@password",
    host="192.30.0.194",
    database="EPM_Dashboard",
    query={"driver": "SQL Server Native Client 11.0"},
)
engine = sa.create_engine(connection_url)
```

For those who are curious, the stringified version of the URL is

```py
print(connection_url.render_as_string(hide_password=False))
# mssql+pyodbc://someuser:fancy%40password@192.30.0.194/EPM_Dashboard?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0
```

but note that it is **NOT** necessary to convert the URL object to string before passing it to `create_engine()`.

Comment: if you need to specify a port, you can do `host="192.30.0.194,1433"`

Comment: Note: That syntax is specific to SQL Server. `URL.create()` will also construct the correct connection string if we use `host="192.30.0.194", port=49242`