# SqlAlchemy Correct way to create url for engine

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

What is the best / correct way to create a `url` which needs to be passed to `sqlalchemy.create_engine`? https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine

My connection string looks similar to this:

```
con_str = "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:somedb.database.windows.net,1433;Database=somedbname;Uid=someuser;Pwd=some++pass=;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no"
```

If I do ([Connecting to SQL Server 2012 using sqlalchemy and pyodbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15750711/connecting-to-sql-server-2012-using-sqlalchemy-and-pyodbc)):

```
import urllib

import sqlalchemy as sa


connection_url = sa.engine.URL.create(
    "mssql+pyodbc",
    query={"odbc_connect": urllib.parse.quote_plus(con_str)},
)

print(connection_url.render_as_string(hide_password=False))
```

I get this output:

```
mssql+pyodbc://?odbc_connect=Driver%3D%7BODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server%7D%3BServer%3Dtcp%3Asomedb.database.windows.net%2C1433%3BDatabase%3Dsomedbname%3BUid%3Dsomeuser%3BPwd%3Dsome%2B%2Bpass%3D%3BEncrypt%3Dyes%3BTrustServerCertificate%3Dno
```

But if I do ([How do I use SQLAlchemy create_engine() with password that includes an @](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66371841/how-do-i-use-sqlalchemy-create-engine-with-password-that-includes-an)):

```
connection_url = sa.engine.URL.create(
    drivername="mssql+pyodbc",
    username="someuser",
    password="some++pass=",
    host="tcp:somedb.database.windows.net",
    port=1433,
    database="somedbname",
    query={'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server', 'encrypt': 'yes', 'trustservercertificate': 'no'},
)

print(connection_url.render_as_string(hide_password=False))
```

I get a different output:

```
mssql+pyodbc://someuser:some++pass%3D@[tcp:somedb.database.windows.net]:1433/somedbname?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server&encrypt=yes&trustservercertificate=no
```

Both of them work for general reads but for more obscure uses **they produce different results**.

For example, for a particular piece of code the former option works while the latter option throws:

> ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar(max) to binary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query. (257) (SQLExecDirectW)').

I am assuming the former is correct since the majority of StackOverflow answers provide it as an example. I am interested why different parameters produce such different results and where can I read about it on https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use this database or driver but there is some information in the docs about both your examples.  It seems that they are both supported.

[pass-through-exact-pyodbc-string](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/mssql.html#pass-through-exact-pyodbc-string)

- the docs do not use urllib.parse.quote_plus in this case, maybe try it without it?  maybe it falls back to a different driver?

[hostname-connections](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/mssql.html#hostname-connections)

- their `"trustservercertificate"` is written `"TrustServerCertificate"`, this might not matter as the docs only mention `"driver"` as being special

Comment: urllib.parse.quote_plus is there for passwords with "funny" symbols. It can work without it just as well, indeed.