# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable while trying to access a list

Tags: python, callable

I am trying to run this code where I have a list of lists. I need to add to inner lists, but I get the error

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable.
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here.

```
def createlists():
    global maxchar
    global minchar
    global worddict
    global wordlists

    for i in range(minchar, maxchar + 1):
        wordlists.insert(i, list())
    #add data to list now
    for words in worddict.keys():
        print words
        print  wordlists(len(words)) # <--- Error here.
        (wordlists(len(words))).append(words)  # <-- Error here too
        print "adding word " + words + " at " + str(wordlists(len(words)))
    print wordlists(5)
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

For accessing the elements of a list you need to use the square brackets (`[]`) and not the parenthesis (`()`).

Instead of:

```
print  wordlists(len(words))
```

you need to use:

```
print worldlists[len(words)]
```

And instead of:

```
(wordlists(len(words))).append(words)
```

you need to use:

```
worldlists[len(words)].append(words)
```

Comment: Canonizing the answer, Hence I made a small edit. Do rollback if you feel to do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

To get elements of a list you have to use `list[i]` instead of `list(i)`.

Answer (score 7):

wordlists is not a function, it is a list.  You need the bracket subscript

```
print  wordlists[len(words)]
```

Comment: +1 for identifying that wordlists isn't a function (or some callable object) and hence can't be called with an argument(s), resulting in the given error. For a technical explanation of what makes a Python object callable, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234/what-is-a-callable-in-python. If we want to get really technical about this, we use the square brackets because it is a list data-structure http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists

Answer (score 5):

I also got the error when I called a function that had the same name as another variable that was classified as a list.

Once I sorted out the naming the error was resolved.

Answer (score 3):

You are attempting to call `wordlists` here:

```
print  wordlists(len(words)) <--- Error here.
```

Try:

```
print wordlists[len(words)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `wordlists[len(words)]`. `()` is a function call. When you do `wordlists(..)`, python thinks that you are calling a function called `wordlists` which turns out to be a `list`. Hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

Check your file name in which you have saved your program. If the file name is `wordlists`
then you will get an error. Your filename should not be same as any of methods{functions} that you use in your program.

Answer (score 0):

```
del list
```

above command worked for me

Comment: If you have assigned a variable list, this might happen. Not in the context of this question, but yeah that helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Even I got the same error, but I solved it, I had used many list in my work so I just restarted my kernel (meaning if you are using a notebook such as Jupyter or Google Colab you can just restart and again run all the cells, by doing this your problem will be solved and the error vanishes.

**Thank you**.