# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable /// In ex26 learning Python the hard Way

Tags: python

Here is the output I am receiving, and I am having trouble of what to check for when I re examine my code for the indicated lines.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex27.py", line 93, in <module>
    print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence)
  File "ex27.py", line 35, in print_first_and_last_sorted
    words = sort_sentence(sentence)
  File "ex27.py", line 25, in sort_sentence
    return sort_words(words)
```

Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: How about posting the code?

Comment: You are probably trying to refer to an item I'm the list using parentheses instead of square brackets.

Comment: Its like telling the doctor over the phone that your butt hurts, but you refuse to come in to the office and let him look.

Comment: Look at [yano](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1325941/yano)'s answer and my comment on his answer

Answer (score 1):

[Duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735841/python-typeerror-list-object-is-not-callable)

Anyways, when you get this error it means you are trying to call an object (in this case a list) in a way in which a list can't be used to call for a specific object. It's hard to say what exactly is wrong without seeing the code, though.

Comment: I would think that being new to Python and SO, the OP is not familiar enough with either python (to be able to understand the code in the duplicate you posted) or SO itself (to know to look for duplicates first)

Comment: Inspector had it right. Sorry Guys new to SO and this whole world. Very sorry to leave you hanging and to not post the code. I wasn't sure if the question had even posted. Also, I'm still using dial-up, just kidding. Forgive me!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using parentheses rather than brackets to reference an item in a list?

E.g.

```
myList(0) # Incorrect
```

Instead of:

```
myList[0] # Correct
```