# I'm getting "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable". How do I fix this error?

Tags: python, typeerror

I have a simple script:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
myrange = list(range(1, 10))

for number in list:
    if number in myrange:
        print(number, 'is between 1 and 10')
```

However, whenever I attempt to run my script, Python raises an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

What does this error mean? Why am I getting it? And how can I fix it?

Comment: FWIW, I thought this question was going to be a better canonical for this scenario: [TypeError: 'list' object is not callable while trying to access a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735841/typeerror-list-object-is-not-callable-while-trying-to-access-a-list), which I've used as a dupe target.

Comment: I think this example is confusing because it's not redefining a built-in name that causes this error. I get a similar error with `exec("class B: pass\nb = B()\nb()")`. Most people who get `list object is not callable` did not redefine the name `list`.

Comment: @Gribouillis I have to disagree there. The error is posted _is_ because I redefined the builtin name `list`. because of this, I could no longer use the original value of the name `list`. The error your getting OTOH, is caused because you didn't implement a certain special method. I understand that not all `TypeError`s are caused because of redefining built-in names, but doing a qucik search on SO shows that many questions with the title "TypeError: <type>' object is not callable" have made the mistake of redefining a built-in name.

Comment: No, try this `exec("def foo(): return []\nfoo()()")`.  The error is exactly the same as the title of this thread. The meaning of this message is that an instance of list type is not a callable object.

Comment: I know that @Gribouillis. I do realize that **not all `TypeError`s are because of redefining built-in names**. What I am saying is that a good amount of questions I see about `TypeError`s in the Python tag are because the OP redefined a built-in name. Thus, there's benefit in creating a canonical Q&A post dealing specifically with the topic of redefining built-in names and the error it usually causes.

Comment: I agree that this is a good error case to have a canonical Q&A for. But I also think your answer should mention other scenarios that can lead to the same error message. Stuff like `a=[1]; b=a(0)` is pretty common, although I guess we _could_ class such usage as a typo...

Comment: @PM2Ring I do agree with you. I didn't include cases such as those in my answer because I thought we already had a good Q&A for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735841/typeerror-list-object-is-not-callable-while-trying-to-access-a-list. I just didn't want to repeat info. I also figured it was somewhat of a slipper slope. Thinking to myself: _"At what point would you stop calling a `TypeError` cause common?"_ This may just be my laziness though in failing to identify common `TypeError` causes. But if yout hink it'd make for more complete Q&A, I'll try to add that.

Comment: Just add a brief reference at the end, maybe after a `<hr>`. Hopefully, lots of people will come to this page by searching for that error message, so it will be good to redirect them to that other question if they get here for the `some_list(idx)` reason.

Comment: What about the existing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31087111/typeerror-list-object-is-not-callable-in-python? Second google hit for me with the error message.

Comment: @AndrasDeak That's a very valid point you brought up. That answer is pretty good. It's the dupe target I've been using. But there were two main reasons I created this Q&A instead. To put it briefly:
: **(1)** IMHO, the other answer went to in-depth about namespaces and global lookup details, rather than just focusing on the main question. **(2)** I think it would've been good if the answer had talked a bit more about what built-ins are, to make the post more general. Right now, it just seems to localized.

Comment: Your dislike for an *answer* is not a valid reason to make your own Q&A pair. If the *question* is bad (no MCVE, or similar) and can't be edited into shape without invalidating existing answers, then I fully support the creation of a new, better, canonical Q&A. But that does not apply to *answers*. We have a voting system in place that lets the community decide which answer is best. If you write a better answer, yours will eventually rise to the top. By creating your own Q&A you're invalidating all the effort people have put into writing the existing answers and all the votes people have cast.

Comment: I appreciate the comment @Aran-Fey. I understand your concern. I generally agree with what you're saying. The reason I posted a new Q&A pair, rather than post another answer to the question Andras linked to, was because I felt the that the post Andras linked already had a specific focus. Yes my comment to Andras only highlighted the answer, but I still thought the answer was useful and decided it was best to create a new Q&A pair to solely address this topic. I could have molded the question to better suit my topic, but I felt that doing so would somewhat invalidate the top, selected answer.

Comment: (continued from above comment) However, I disagree that I'm invalidating anyone's answer. If I posted an answer on the question that Andras linked too, would I be invalidating the current top answer? I don't think so. I fail to see how posting an answer to a new Q&A is actually distinct. As for invalidating votes, again, I would have to respectfully disagree. It was still the community's choice to choose this new Q&A I created, vs the one Andras linked to. I attempted to justify why I felt I made the right decision in creating a new Q&A pair.

Comment: By the way, I forgot to mention: This question is being [discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381064/1222951). You may want to post your rationale there.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Before you can fully understand what the error means and how to solve, it is important to understand what a built-in name is in Python.

### What is a built-in name?

In Python, a built-in name is a **name that the Python interpreter already has assigned a predefined value**. The value can be either a *function* or *class* object. These names are always made available by default, no matter the scope. Some of the values assigned to these names represent fundamental types of the Python language, while others are simple useful.

As of the latest version of Python - [3.6.2](https://docs.python.org/3/) - there are currently *61* built-in names. A full list of the names and how they should be used, can be found in the documentation section [*Built-in Functions*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#built-in-functions).

An important point to note however, is that **Python *will not* stop you from *re*-assigning builtin names**. Built-in names are not reserved, and Python allows them to be used as variable names as well.

Here is an example using the [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=dict#func-dict) built-in:

```
>>> dict = {}
>>> dict
{}
>>>
```

As you can see, Python allowed us to assign the `dict` name, to *reference a dictionary object*.

### What does "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable" mean?

To put it simply, the reason the error is occurring is because you ***re-assigned*** the *builtin name* `list` in the script:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

When you did this, **you overwrote the predefined value of the built-in name**. This means you can no longer use the predefined value of `list`, which is a class object representing Python list.

Thus, when you tried to use the `list` class to create a new list from a `range` object:

```
myrange = list(range(1, 10))
```

Python raised an error. The reason the error says "'list' object is not callable", is because as said above, the name `list` was referring to a list object. So the above would be the equivalent of doing:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5](range(1, 10))
```

Which of course makes no sense. You cannot call a list object.

### How can I fix the error?

If you are getting a similar error such as this one saying an "object is not callable", chances are you used a builtin name as a variable in your code. In this case the fix is as simple as renaming the offending variable. For example, to fix the above code, we could rename our `list` variable to `ints`:

```
ints = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] # Rename "list" to "ints"
myrange = list(range(1, 10))

for number in ints: # Renamed "list" to "ints"
    if number in myrange:
        print(number, 'is between 1 and 10')
```

[PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) - the official Python style guide - includes many recommendations on naming variables.

This is a very common error new and old Python users make. This is why it's important to always avoid using built-in names as variables such as `str`, `dict`, `list`, `range`, etc.

Many linters and IDEs will warn you when you attempt to use a built-in name as a variable. If your frequently make this mistake, it may be worth your time to invest in one of these programs.

### I didn't rename a built-in name, but I'm still getting "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable". What gives?

Another common cause for the above error is attempting to index a list using parenthesis (`()`) rather than square brackets (`[]`). For example:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2]
>>> lst(0)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#32>", line 1, in <module>
    lst(0)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

For an explanation of the full problem and what can be done to fix it, see [TypeError: 'list' object is not callable while trying to access a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735841/typeerror-list-object-is-not-callable-while-trying-to-access-a-list).

Answer (score -4):

Here is the [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)!

```
>>> []()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Try also `{}()` and `()()`. The message `TypeError: 'X' object is not callable` means that you wrote `expression(some_arguments)` where `expression` is an instance of the `X` type, and this type *doesn't support* to be used in a function call syntax. Most of the time you wrote this because you thought `expression` was a function or some other callable type.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. My answer addresses the 'How do I fix the error?' part. Python doesn't forbid to redefine the name 'list', but it refuses to call an instance of the list type. For all practical debugging purposes, this answer works.