# 'int' uncallable in python code

Tags: python

I've been asked to write a program that using central difference

```
"Central difference formula"

def difc(f,x,h):
    h = float(h)
    return (f(x + h) - f(x - h))/2*h

"Entraphy function"
f = 259.8*(3.782*x - 2.997*(10**-3)*(x**2)/2 + 9.847*(10**-6)*(x**3)/3 - 9.681*(10**-9)*(x**4)/4 + 3.243*(10**-12)*(x**5)/5 - 1.064*10**3)
"temperature"
x = 500

print (difc(f,500,5))
```

When I run the code I get the error

```
line 9, in derivative 
    return (f(x+h) - f(x))/h
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable"
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I'm getting "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable". How do I fix this error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45740182/im-getting-typeerror-list-object-is-not-callable-how-do-i-fix-this-error)

Answer (score 2):

seems that `f` is not a function but a value (even if `x` isn't defined at this point...). Maybe you want to define an actual *function*, and with your formatting, `lambda` is the perfect candidate:

```
f = lambda x: 259.8*(3.782*x - 2.997*(10**-3)*(x**2)/2 + 9.847*(10**-6)*(x**3)/3 - 9.681*(10**-9)*(x**4)/4 + 3.243*(10**-12)*(x**5)/5 - 1.064*10**3)
```

Comment: Also I wouldn't make it a `lambda` a `def` function would be just as well, especially if it's that long (but that's just a personal dislike for non-inline `lambda`s). :D

Comment: @MSeifert yes, but it was the opportunity to show that `lambda` isn't so difficult to comprehend.