# TypeError: 'zip' object is not callable in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I'm trying to zip 2 simple lists in Python 3.5, and can't figure out how to access the contents. I've read now that `zip()` is a generator, and I have to call `list(zip())` if I want to store the contents. However, I'm experiencing an error when doing so.

For example:

```
row = [1, 2, 3]
col = ['A', 'B', 'C']
z = zip(row, col)
```

When I call 'z', I see the following:

```
>>> z
<zip object at 0x0283C8F0>
```

But when I call `list(z)`, I get the following error:

```
>>> list(z)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'zip' object is not callable
```

I also get the same error when attempting to assign the list to a variable, such as:

```
l = list(zip(row, col))
```

Apologies if this has already been answered, but I cannot for the life of me find a solution via search. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Interesting. Is that all the code you have for the testing? I would assume you overwrote `zip` somewhere in your file globally

Comment: [mcve] please. you _must_ have tampered heavily with `list` & `zip`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I'm getting "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable". How do I fix this error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45740182/im-getting-typeerror-list-object-is-not-callable-how-do-i-fix-this-error)

Comment: Thanks. You are correct - I was experimenting with `list` and `zip` in the terminal, and scrolling back I noticed at one point I had naively named my example list "list", which caused my problem. First post... next time I'll close my terminal and try it again.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

that happens when you redefine `list` as `zip()` (which is probably what you did but didn't show us):

```
>>> list = zip()
```

now `list` is a `zip` object (not the `zip` class)

```
>>> list(z)
```

now you're attempting to call a `zip` object

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 301, in runcode
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'zip' object is not callable
>>>
```

just

```
del list
```

(or start from a fresh interpreter)

and everything's back to normal

Comment: This fixed it!! Thanks for the quick and informative answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use this in a `.map` re-assignment, you'd have to wrap it in `dict`, e.g.

```py
df.Account = df.Account.map(dict(zip(list1, list2)))
```