# Simple *args function not working in Python

Tags: python, function, args

the following is getting a "int object is not callable" error message:

```
def plus(*args):
    return sum(args)

plus(6, 7, 8)
```

Any ideas as to why?  This is taken straight from a online tutorial session so I am sure others have noticed the same.

Thanks

Comment: You assigned something to `sum`. Don't do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I'm getting "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable". How do I fix this error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45740182/im-getting-typeerror-list-object-is-not-callable-how-do-i-fix-this-error)

Comment: The given code does not reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to `print sum` you'll see that it prints some value.
The syntax is correct (in both Python 3 and 2.7).
The error is basically saying: `sum` cannot be called as function, because you assigned something to it that is not callable.

Tested your code [here](https://www.python.org/shell/) and [here](http://live.sympy.org/), and works perfectly

Comment: Thanks.  I copied and pasted into a new file and it worked fine, not sure what happened.  Ill "check" your answer as accepted when it allows me too