# Using regex in Python if statement

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to figure out how to incorporate regex into a python if statement. I have a pandas dataframe where I am iterating over the rows and want to perform an  action every time the row has a specific combination of text. The regex should match any 7 character string that begins with a capital letter followed by 6 numbers (ie. R142389)

```
        for index, row in df1.iterrows():
             if row[4] == REGEX HERE:
                  Perform Action
```

Am I going about this the right way? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, just use `match`, which will only match at the beginning of the string it is being compared to.  You would have to use `search` to search the entire string.

A bit of explanation about the regex:

`^` asserts position at start of the string

`[A-Z]` A-Z a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index 90) (case sensitive)

`\d{6}` matches a digit (equal to `[0-9]`)
`{6}` Quantifier — Matches exactly 6 times

`$` asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string

```
import re

regex = re.compile('^[A-Z]\d{6}$')

possibles = ['R142389', 'hello', 'J123456']

for line in possibles:
    if regex.match(line):
        print(line)
```

Output:

```
R142389
J123456
```

Comment: Be careful with `str = ['R142389', 'hello', 'J123456']`. Your overwriting a built-in name which can cause [strange errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45740182/im-getting-typeerror-list-object-is-not-callable-how-do-i-fix-this-error) and the like. It'd would be best to use a name such as `strs` instead. Anyway's, nice answer. +1

Comment: If you recommend using `match`, you should mention that it will only match patterns at the beginning of the string. `search` will find matches in the whole string.

Comment: @ChristianDean whoops, fixed

Comment: @skrrgwasme Perhaps, but note that the OP _explictly_ said _"The regex should match any 7 character string that **begins** with a capital letter followed by 6 number"_.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `re` module

```
import re

re.search(pattern, string, flags=0)
```

where `pattern` is the regular expression to be matched, `string` is the string going to be searched and `flags` which are optional modifiers. This funcion returns `None` when there is no match.

Here is the  `re` documentation:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

And here is an example of the implementation: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm