# Could not cast a String to a List

Tags: python, types

I got so frustrated because of this error message here and couldn't figure out what went wrong with such a simple code:

```
secret_word_list = list('trang')

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

`secret_word_list` is a new variable. where does the 'tuple' type come from? Also if I assign the string to a variable, can I cast it to a string just by calling its name. For example:

```
string = 'abc'
list = list(string)
```

I tried but the same error message kept popping up.

Also, I write this in Spyder. If I wrote in PythonTutor, things would go well.

Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: You must have assigned a `tuple` to a variable named `list` earlier in your code. See [_I'm getting “TypeError: 'list' object is not callable”. How do I fix this error?_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45740182/im-getting-typeerror-list-object-is-not-callable-how-do-i-fix-this-error).

Comment: And this, boys and girls, is why you don't shadow built-ins like `list`.

Comment: seems like @ChristianDean is right here, please check your code again.

Comment: It works exactly one time, :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is being caused because you're shadowing a builtin keyword of Python: `list`.

Never create variables with names of builtin keywords.

Your code works perfectly fine if you choose another variable name:

```
>> string = 'abc'
>> my_list = list(string)
>> print(my_list)
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

I suspect you're getting a `TypeError` because you previously assigned a tuple to a variable called `list`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what it does when I run your code in a fresh interpreter:

```
>>> secret_word_list = list('trang')
>>> secret_word_list
['t', 'r', 'a', 'n', 'g']
>>>
```

In other words, it behaves as expected.
If you take a closer look at the error you get, you can understand that Python sees that a tuple is being called:

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

The only call is on `list`.
Therefore, `list` is a tuple.
This can only mean that `list` has been rebound somewhere in your code.

You need to find the line where you wrote something like

```
list = ...
```

and use a different name instead of `list`.