# Difficulty with list script

Tags: python

Write a function named `sum_values` that takes a list as a parameter and returns the sum of the values at indices `11, 8, 5 and 1`f. You may assume the input will be large enough to have values at all these indices.

```
def sum_values(list):
    value = sum(list(11)) + sum(list(8)) + sum(list(5)) + sum(list(1))
    return value
```

I am getting list object is not callable and error input.

Comment: use '[]' instead of '()'  for example: `list[11]`

Comment: Also remove all the `sum` calls, they arent doing anything.

Comment: Also, `list` is the name of a built-in class in `Python`, so you should really not use that as a variable name (even though it works).

Answer (score 1):

```
def sum_values(a_list):

    value = a_list[11] + a_list[8] + a_list[5] + a_list[1]
    return value


sum_values([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]) #29
```

the sum() function will work if the list is something like [[1,1,1],2,3,4], then sum(list[0]) will return 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can just return the concatenated indices

```
def sum_values(lista):
    return lista[11] + lista[8] + lista[5] + lista[1]

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
print(sum_values(l))
```

> ```
> 29
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

def sum_values(lst):
    result = a[11] + a[8] + a[5] + a[1]
    return result

print(sum_values(a)) # will print 29
```

For details on the error that you got you can [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45740182/im-getting-typeerror-list-object-is-not-callable-how-do-i-fix-this-error)

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension.

```
my_test_list = [10, 15, 6, 84, 1, 9, 12, 122, 242, 5, 10, 18, 1, 0, 0, 6, 27]
indices = [11,8,5,1]

def sum_values(my_list):
    return sum([my_test_list[index] for index in range(0, len(my_test_list)) if index in indices])

print(sum_values(my_test_list))
```

Output:

```
>>> 284
```

This will only sum items if they are at the indices specified in the indices list. Hope this helps.