# Collections.defaultdict difference with normal dict

Tags: python, dictionary, default-value, defaultdict

I've read the examples in python docs, but still can't figure out what this method means. Can somebody help? Here are two examples from the python docs

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict

>>> s = 'mississippi'
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> for k in s:
...     d[k] += 1
...
>>> d.items()
dict_items([('m', 1), ('i', 4), ('s', 4), ('p', 2)])
```

and

```
>>> s = [('yellow', 1), ('blue', 2), ('yellow', 3), ('blue', 4), ('red', 1)]
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for k, v in s:
...     d[k].append(v)
...
>>> d.items()
[('blue', [2, 4]), ('red', [1]), ('yellow', [1, 3])]
```

the parameters `int` and `list` are for what?

Comment: BTW, depending upon your use case, **do not forget** to freeze the defaultdict for read-only use by setting its `default_factory = None` after you've finished populating the defaultdict. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465681/exposing-defaultdict-as-a-regular-dict).

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17215400/python-format-string-unused-named-arguments

Answer (score 873, accepted):

Usually, a Python dictionary throws a `KeyError` if you try to get an item with a key that is not currently in the dictionary.  The `defaultdict` in contrast will simply create any items that you try to access (provided of course they do not exist yet).  To create such a "default" item, it calls the function object that you pass to the constructor (more precisely, it's an arbitrary "callable" object, which includes function and type objects).  For the first example, default items are created using `int()`, which will return the integer object `0`.  For the second example, default items are created using `list()`, which returns a new empty list object.

Comment: Is it functionally different than using d.get(key, default_val) ?

Comment: @Ambareesh `d.get(key, default)` won't ever modify your dictionary – it will just return the default and leave the dictionary unchanged. `defaultdict`, on the other hand, will _insert_ a key into the dictionary if it isn't there yet. This is a big difference; see the examples in the question to understand why.

Comment: How do we know what is the default value for each type? 0 for int() and [] for list() are intuitive, but there can also be more complex or self-defined types.

Comment: @Sean `defaultdict` calls whatever constructor you pass in. If you pass in an a type `T`, values will be constructed using `T()`. Not all types can be constructed without passing in any parameters. If you want to construct such a type, you need a wrapper function, or something like `functools.partial(T, arg1, arg2)`.

Comment: Or even more easily: a lambda. `defaultdict(lambda : T(arg1, arg2))`.

Answer (score 310):

`defaultdict` means that if a key is not found in the dictionary, then instead of a `KeyError` being thrown, a new entry is created. The type of this new entry is given by the argument of defaultdict.

For example:

```
somedict = {}
print(somedict[3]) # KeyError

someddict = defaultdict(int)
print(someddict[3]) # print int(), thus 0
```

Comment: "The type of this new pair is given by the argument of defaultdict." Note that the argument can be **any** callable object -  not just type functions. For example if foo was a function that returned "bar", foo could be used as an argument to default dict and if a non-present key was accessed, its value would be set to "bar".

Comment: Or if you just want to return "bar":  somedict = defaultdict(lambda:"bar")

Comment: Fourth line returned `0` the integer, if it was `someddict = defaultdict(list)` it returns `[ ]`. Is 0 the default integer? Or [ ] the default list?

Comment: Neither. `0` is immutable - in CPython all values from `-5` to `256` are cached singletons but this is implementation-specific behaviour - in both cases a new instance is "created" each time with `int()` or `list()`. That way, `d[k].append(v)` can work without filling the dictionary with references to the same list, which would render `defaultdict` almost useless. If this were the behaviour, `defaultdict` would take a value, not a lambda, as a parameter. (Sorry for the terrible explanation!)

Answer (score 143):

## defaultdict

"The standard dictionary includes the method setdefault() for retrieving a value and establishing a default if the value does not exist. By contrast, `defaultdict` lets the caller specify the default(value to be returned) up front when the container is initialized."

as defined by *Doug Hellmann* in *The Python Standard Library by Example*

### How to use defaultdict

#### Import defaultdict

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
```

#### Initialize defaultdict

Initialize it by passing

> [callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234/what-is-a-callable-in-python) as its first argument(mandatory)

```
>>> d_int = defaultdict(int)
>>> d_list = defaultdict(list)
>>> def foo():
...     return 'default value'
... 
>>> d_foo = defaultdict(foo)
>>> d_int
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {})
>>> d_list
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {})
>>> d_foo
defaultdict(<function foo at 0x7f34a0a69578>, {})
```

> [**kwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/understanding-kwargs-in-python) as its second argument(optional)

```
>>> d_int = defaultdict(int, a=10, b=12, c=13)
>>> d_int
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'a': 10, 'c': 13, 'b': 12})
```

or

```
>>> kwargs = {'a':10,'b':12,'c':13}
>>> d_int = defaultdict(int, **kwargs)
>>> d_int
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'a': 10, 'c': 13, 'b': 12})
```

#### How does it works

As is a child class of standard dictionary, it can perform all the same functions.

But in case of passing an unknown key it returns the default value instead of error. For ex:

```
>>> d_int['a']
10
>>> d_int['d']
0
>>> d_int
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'a': 10, 'c': 13, 'b': 12, 'd': 0})
```

In case you want to change default value overwrite default_factory:

```
>>> d_int.default_factory = lambda: 1
>>> d_int['e']
1
>>> d_int
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7f34a0a91578>, {'a': 10, 'c': 13, 'b': 12, 'e': 1, 'd': 0})
```

or

```
>>> def foo():
...     return 2
>>> d_int.default_factory = foo
>>> d_int['f']
2
>>> d_int
defaultdict(<function foo at 0x7f34a0a0a140>, {'a': 10, 'c': 13, 'b': 12, 'e': 1, 'd': 0, 'f': 2})
```

#### Examples in the Question

**Example 1**

As int has been passed as default_factory, any unknown key will return 0 by default.

Now as the string is passed in the loop, it will increase the count of those alphabets in d.

```
>>> s = 'mississippi'
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> d.default_factory
<type 'int'>
>>> for k in s:
...     d[k] += 1
>>> d.items()
[('i', 4), ('p', 2), ('s', 4), ('m', 1)]
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'i': 4, 'p': 2, 's': 4, 'm': 1})
```

**Example 2**

As a list has been passed as default_factory, any unknown(non-existent) key will return [ ](ie. list) by default.

Now as the list of tuples is passed in the loop, it will append the value in the d[color]

```
>>> s = [('yellow', 1), ('blue', 2), ('yellow', 3), ('blue', 4), ('red', 1)]
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> d.default_factory
<type 'list'>
>>> for k, v in s:
...     d[k].append(v)
>>> d.items()
[('blue', [2, 4]), ('red', [1]), ('yellow', [1, 3])]
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'blue': [2, 4], 'red': [1], 'yellow': [1, 3]})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know how to make the constant always different? I explain: `defaultdict(lambda: 'string', **kwargs)` will not work as expected because all new keys will share the same instance of 'string'. How can I provide a copy each time? Note that `defaultdict(lambda: copy.copy('string'), **kwargs)` does not work because copy is evaluated only once.

Answer (score 42):

Dictionaries are a convenient way to store data for later retrieval by name (key). Keys must be unique, immutable objects, and are typically strings. The values in a dictionary can be anything. For many applications, the values are simple types such as integers and strings.

It gets more interesting when the values in a dictionary are collections (lists, dicts, etc.) In this case, the value (an empty list or dict) must be initialized the first time a given key is used. While this is relatively easy to do manually, the defaultdict type automates and simplifies these kinds of operations. 
A defaultdict works exactly like a normal dict, but it is initialized with a function (“default factory”) that takes no arguments and provides the default value for a nonexistent key.

A defaultdict will never raise a KeyError. Any key that does not exist gets the value returned by the default factory.

```
from collections import defaultdict
ice_cream = defaultdict(lambda: 'Vanilla')

ice_cream['Sarah'] = 'Chunky Monkey'
ice_cream['Abdul'] = 'Butter Pecan'

print(ice_cream['Sarah'])
>>>Chunky Monkey

print(ice_cream['Joe'])
>>>Vanilla
```

## Here is another example on How using defaultdict, we can reduce complexity

```
from collections import defaultdict
# Time complexity O(n^2)
def delete_nth_naive(array, n):
    ans = []
    for num in array:
        if ans.count(num) < n:
            ans.append(num)
    return ans

# Time Complexity O(n), using hash tables.
def delete_nth(array,n):
    result = []
    counts = defaultdict(int)

    for i in array:
        if counts[i] < n:
            result.append(i)
            counts[i] += 1
    return result


x = [1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3]
print(delete_nth(x, n=2))
print(delete_nth_naive(x, n=2))
```

In conclusion, whenever you need a dictionary, and each element’s value should start with a default value, use a defaultdict.

Comment: At last, a clear, simple and pythonic example.  Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

There is a great explanation of defaultdicts here: http://ludovf.net/blog/python-collections-defaultdict/

Basically, the parameters **int** and **list** are functions that you pass. Remember that Python accepts function names as arguments. **int** returns 0 by default and **list** returns an empty list when called with parentheses.

In normal dictionaries, if in your example I try calling `d[a]`, I will get an error (KeyError), since only keys m, s, i and p exist and key a has not been initialized. But in a defaultdict, it takes a function name as an argument, when you try to use a key that has not been initialized, it simply calls the function you passed in and assigns its return value as the value of the new key.

Answer (score 18):

The behavior of `defaultdict` can be easily mimicked using `dict.setdefault` instead of `d[key]` in every call.

In other words, the code:

```python
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

print(d['key'])                        # empty list []
d['key'].append(1)                     # adding constant 1 to the list
print(d['key'])                        # list containing the constant [1]
```

is equivalent to:

```python
d = dict()

print(d.setdefault('key', list()))     # empty list []
d.setdefault('key', list()).append(1)  # adding constant 1 to the list
print(d.setdefault('key', list()))     # list containing the constant [1]
```

The only difference is that, using `defaultdict`, the list constructor is called only once, and using `dict.setdefault` the list constructor is called more often (but the code may be rewriten to avoid this, if really needed).

Some may argue there is a performance consideration, but this topic is a minefield.  [This post shows there isn't a big performance gain in using defaultdict, for example.](https://tomron.net/2014/08/25/setdefault-vs-get-vs-defaultdict/)

IMO, defaultdict is a collection that adds more confusion than benefits to the code.  Useless for me, but others may think different.

Answer (score 12):

Since the question is about "how it works", some readers may want to see more nuts and bolts. Specifically, the method in question is the `__missing__(key)` method. See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects .

More concretely, this answer shows how to make use of `__missing__(key)` in a practical way:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17956989/1593924

To clarify what 'callable' means, here's an interactive session (from 2.7.6 but should work in v3 too):

```
>>> x = int
>>> x
<type 'int'>
>>> y = int(5)
>>> y
5
>>> z = x(5)
>>> z
5

>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> dd = defaultdict(int)
>>> dd
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {})
>>> dd = defaultdict(x)
>>> dd
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {})
>>> dd['a']
0
>>> dd
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'a': 0})
```

That was the most typical use of defaultdict (except for the pointless use of the x variable). You can do the same thing with 0 as the explicit default value, but not with a simple value:

```
>>> dd2 = defaultdict(0)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    dd2 = defaultdict(0)
TypeError: first argument must be callable
```

Instead, the following works because it passes in a simple function (it creates on the fly a nameless function which takes no arguments and always returns 0):

```
>>> dd2 = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
>>> dd2
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x02C4C130>, {})
>>> dd2['a']
0
>>> dd2
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x02C4C130>, {'a': 0})
>>>
```

And with a different default value:

```
>>> dd3 = defaultdict(lambda: 1)
>>> dd3
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x02C4C170>, {})
>>> dd3['a']
1
>>> dd3
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x02C4C170>, {'a': 1})
>>>
```

Answer (score 11):

My own 2¢: you can also subclass defaultdict:

```
class MyDict(defaultdict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        value = [None, None]
        self[key] = value
        return value
```

This could come in handy for very complex cases.

Answer (score 10):

Well, defaultdict can also raise keyerror in the following case:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict()
print(d[3]) #raises keyerror
```

Always remember to give argument to the defaultdict like

```
d = defaultdict(int)
```

Answer (score 9):

The defaultdict tool is a container in the collections class of Python. It's similar to the usual dictionary (dict) container, but it has one difference: The value fields' data type is specified upon initialization.

For example:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

d['python'].append("awesome")

d['something-else'].append("not relevant")

d['python'].append("language")

for i in d.items():

    print i
```

This prints:

```
('python', ['awesome', 'language'])
('something-else', ['not relevant'])
```

Comment: "The value fields' data type is specified upon initialization": this is not correct. An element factory function is provided. Here `list` is the function to call to fill in a missing value, not the type of the objects to create. For example, to have a default value of `1`, you'd use `lambda:1` which is obviously not a type.

Answer (score 7):

In short:

`defaultdict(int)` - the argument int indicates that the values will be int type.

`defaultdict(list)` - the argument list indicates that the values will be list type.

Answer (score 4):

I think its best used in place of a switch case statement. Imagine if we have a switch case statement as below:

```
option = 1

switch(option) {
    case 1: print '1st option'
    case 2: print '2nd option'
    case 3: print '3rd option'
    default: return 'No such option'
}
```

There is no `switch` case statements available in python. We can achieve the same by using `defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def default_value(): return "Default Value"
dd = defaultdict(default_value)

dd[1] = '1st option'
dd[2] = '2nd option'
dd[3] = '3rd option'

print(dd[4])    
print(dd[5])    
print(dd[3])
```

It prints:

```
Default Value
Default Value
3rd option
```

In the above snippet `dd` has no keys 4 or 5 and hence it prints out a default value which we have configured in a helper function. This is quite nicer than a raw dictionary where a `KeyError` is thrown if key is not present. From this it is evident that `defaultdict` more like a switch case statement where we can avoid a complicated `if-elif-elif-else` blocks.

One more good example that impressed me a lot from [this site](https://www.accelebrate.com/blog/using-defaultdict-python/) is:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> food_list = 'spam spam spam spam spam spam eggs spam'.split()
>>> food_count = defaultdict(int) # default value of int is 0
>>> for food in food_list:
...     food_count[food] += 1 # increment element's value by 1
...
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'eggs': 1, 'spam': 7})
>>>
```

If we try to access any items other than `eggs` and `spam` we will get a count of 0.

Answer (score 4):

Without `defaultdict`, you can probably assign new values to unseen keys but you cannot modify it. For example:

```
import collections
d = collections.defaultdict(int)
for i in range(10):
  d[i] += i
print(d)
# Output: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9})

import collections
d = {}
for i in range(10):
  d[i] += i
print(d)
# Output: Traceback (most recent call last): File "python", line 4, in <module> KeyError: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard dictionary includes the method setdefault() for retrieving a value and establishing a default if the value does not exist. By contrast, defaultdict lets the caller specify the default up front when the container is initialized.

```
import collections

def default_factory():
    return 'default value'

d = collections.defaultdict(default_factory, foo='bar')
print 'd:', d
print 'foo =>', d['foo']
print 'bar =>', d['bar']
```

This works well as long as it is appropriate for all keys to have the same default. It can be especially useful if the default is a type used for aggregating or accumulating values, such as a list, set, or even int. The standard library documentation includes several examples of using defaultdict this way.

```
$ python collections_defaultdict.py

d: defaultdict(<function default_factory at 0x100468c80>, {'foo': 'bar'})
foo => bar
bar => default value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#dictinary and defaultdict

normaldictionary=dict()
print(type(normaldictionary))
#print(normaldictionary["keynotexisit"])
#Above normal dictionary give an error as key not present

from collections import defaultdict
defaultdict1=defaultdict()
print(type(defaultdict1))
#print(defaultdict1['keynotexisit'])
######################################

from collections import defaultdict
default2=defaultdict(int)
print(default2['keynotexist'])
```

https://msatutorpy.medium.com/different-between-dictionary-and-defaultdictionary-cb215f682971