# Python and collections.counter - how to make elements dynamic

Tags: python

I need to add items to a counter and needs to be more dynamic.

```
  hash_data = [{'campaign_id': 'cid2504649263',
  'country': 'AU',
  'impressions': 9000,
  'region': 'Cairns',
  'utcdt': datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 4, 6, 0)},
 {'campaign_id': 'cid2504649263',
  'country': 'AU',
  'impressions': 3000,
  'region': 'Cairns',
  'utcdt': datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 4, 6, 0)},
 {'campaign_id': 'cid2504649263',
  'country': 'AU',
  'impressions': 3000,
  'utcdt': datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 4, 7, 0)}]
```

For example, then last element in the list of hashes does not contain region.  Yet the below is how I add elements and will get an error.

```
C = Counter()
for item in hash_data:
    C[item['utcdt'],item['campaign_id'], item['country'], item['region']] += item[metric]
```

Ideally something like this but of course not work

```
C = Counter()
for item in hash_data:
    m1 = item.keys()
    m2 = []
    for i in ml:
        if i!='impression':
           ms.add(i)
    C[ml] += item[metric]
```

Comment: What default value would you assume for region if it does not exist? Why don't you use `item.get('region', default)`?

Comment: @mg007 you should add `item.get('region','default')` as an answer.

Comment: It need to be dynainc..nit just region....what if I have 100 keys?

Comment: So the key in your Counter is the intersection of your common fields?

Answer (score 1):

```
C = Counter()
for item in hash_data:
  C[tuple(item.values())] += item[metric]
```

Comment: Not a good idea, because two dictionaries may have different key subsets but the same values

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, you can use the [`dict.get`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) with a predefined default value which will be returned in case the key is not present in the dict.

```
default_region = 'default_region'
...
...
item.get('region', default_region)
```

If you have many keys which you think might be absent from your dict, you can use [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) if that suits your purpose ([See this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5900578/155813)). Alternatively, you can simply create a dict of default values containing all possible keys and their corresponding default values. A small example could be:

```
defaults = {
            'campaign_id': 'default_campaign_id',
            'country': 'default_country',
            'impressions': -1,
            'region': 'default_region',
            'utcdt': datetime.datetime.min,
           }

for item in hash_data:
    C[tuple(item.get(k, dv) for k, dv in defaults.items() if k != metric)] += item.get(metric, defaults[metric])
```

HTH!