# Python defaultdict that does not insert missing values

Tags: python, collections, defaultdict

So the [defaultdict documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) mentions that, if an item is missing, the value returned by `default_factory` "is inserted in the dictionary for the key, and returned."  That's great most of the time, but what I actually want in this case is for the value to be returned but **not** inserted into the defaultdict.

I figured I could probably subclass defaultdict and override... I guess `__missing__`?  Not sure.  What's the best way to go about this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can subclass `dict` and implement `__missing__`:

```
class missingdict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return 'default'  # note, does *not* set self[key]
```

Demo:

```
>>> d = missingdict()
>>> d['foo']
'default'
>>> d
{}
```

You *could* subclass `defaultdict` too, you'd get the factory handling plus copy and pickle support thrown in:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class missingdict(defaultdict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return self.default_factory()
```

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> class missingdict(defaultdict):
...     def __missing__(self, key):
...         return self.default_factory() 
... 
>>> d = missingdict(list)
>>> d['foo']
[]
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {})
```

but, as you can see, the `__repr__` does lie about its name.

Comment: That's perfect.  I'll probably go with the defaultdict route to get the copy support.  Thanks!

Comment: Can I set a default value for `d.pop("unloaded_key")`?

Comment: @Lerner: `dict.pop()` takes a second argument for the default. `dict.pop()` will *not* consult `__missing__`, as do most other methods; only `dict.__getitem__` does (so `d[missingkey]`).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I hope that there exists a magic function by which I can set a default value for other methods like dict.pop("missingkey"). :( Is it possible?

Comment: @Lerner: There is not. Just create your own; you are already subclassing `dict`, so just add `def pop(self, *args): try: return super().pop(*args) except KeyError: return self.__missing__()`. Adjust as needed if `__missing__` sets the key in the dictionary first.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You're awesome guy.

Answer (score 0):

It's even simpler than subclassing. While **dict[key]** adds the key, **dict.get(key, default=None)** will NOT add the key to the dictionary:

```
import collections

d = collections.defaultdict(int)

assert d['test1'] == 0

print(d)
# defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'test1': 0})

assert d.get('test2', 0) == 0
# for a more generic version, use `d.default_factory()` instead of 0

print(d)
# defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'test1': 0})
# => did NOT insert a key for 'test2' =)
```

Comment: In case there is objections that this goes against the purpose of using a DEFAULTdict -- in a way yes, but in my particular use case I'm also utilizing a defaultdict update à la `d[key] += 1` somewhere else in the code so it's still justified over a vanilla dict :-)

Comment: Just to be clear, are you using `d[key] += 1` to insert `default+1` at `d[key]`, while intending `value = d[key]` to return the default without modifying the dictionary?

Comment: `d[key]` does insert the default key (0), `d.get(key, 0)` does not