# Key error in dictionary - python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries:
One is :

```
data_obt={'Sim_1':{'sig1':[1,2,3],'sig2':[4,5,6]},'Sim_2':{'sig3':[7,8,9],'sig4':[10,11,12]},'Com_1':{'sig5':[13,14,15],'sig6':[16,17,18]},'Com_2':{'sig7':[19,20,21],'sig9':[128,23,24]}}
```

Other one is:

```
simdict={'sig1':'Bit 1','sig2':'Bit 2','sig3':'Bit 3','sig4':'Bit 4','sig5':'Bit 5','sig6':'Bit 6','sig7':'Bit 7','sig9':''}
```

Now I have to do `return_data[fpath].append(data_obt[key][item])`, where `fpath = 'sig9',key='Com_2'` and `item = 'sig9'`

But when I tried to execute this it is throwing error like : `KeyError: 'sig9'`

My expected `return_data` is `{'sig9':[128,23,24]}`

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Are you using, like, any particular language?

Comment: @matt looks like python . anyways, what's return_data?

Comment: It is python. My expected return_data is {'sig9':[128,23,24]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, `return_data` is another dict. If so, it doesn't (as of yet) have a key named `fpath` (which is 'sig9'). Hence, the error.

To avoid it, you should either use [defaultdict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900578/how-collections-defaultdict-work), or initialize this element as an empty list every time you come across a new key.