# In Python merge two dictionaries so that their keys are added/subtracted

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

I've two dictionaries, output of `factorint` from `sympy.ntheory`. I need to merge them so that the common keys gets their values summed up, i.e. `MergedDict[key] =  Dict1[key] + Dict2[key]`, while unique keys remain same.

Also I need to get a `merged` dictionary with the common keys being differenced, i.e. `MergedDict[key] =  Dict1[key] - Dict2[key]`. Here `Dict2` keys will be always a subset of `Dict1` keys, so no problem of negative numbers.

I've tried to follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31018158/). But I'm unable to make it work. So far my approach has been as follows:

```
from sympy.ntheory import factorint
from collections import defaultdict

d=factorint(12)
dd = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
for key, values_dict in d.items():
            for date, integer in values_dict.items():
                dd[key] += integer

for n in range(2,6):
    u = factorint(n)

    for key, values_dict in u.items():
        for date, integer in values_dict.items():
            dd[key] += integer
```

It gives the error `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'items'`. The code above in only for the summing up part. Yet to do anything on the differencing part, assuming that summing up can be changed to work for differencing in case of common keys.

Comment: d is a `dict` object as output by `factorint`, not sure what you mean by "why are you expecting a dict?". If the approach is wrong please tell.

Comment: yes factorint is a dict but the values stored in the dict are not dictionaries. `values_dict` in your code is an int not a dict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you goal is but `factorint` gives you key/value pairs of ints so you should be summing the values, you are trying to call `items` on each val from the `dict` which is an integer and obviously not going to work:

```
    from sympy.ntheory import factorint
    from collections import defaultdict

    d=factorint(12)
    dd = defaultdict(int)
    for key, val in d.items():
       dd[key] += val

    for n in range(2, 6):
        u = factorint(n)
        for key, val in u.items():
                dd[key] += val

    print(dd)
```

Output:

```
 defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {2: 5, 3: 2, 5: 1})
```

factorint being a dict cannot have duplicate keys so the first loop cann be done using update:

```
d = factorint(12)
dd = defaultdict(int)
dd.update(d)

for n in range(2, 6):
    u = factorint(n)
    for key, val in u.items():
            dd[key] += val
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. Python newbie, so many things to understand. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @Frash, no worries, if you get stuck on something `print` is your friend for debugging

Answer (score 1):

It seems that [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) can do most of what you want. It might be as simple as (untested, I do not have sympy installed):

```
from collections import Counter
cnt1 = Counter(Dict1)
cnt2 = Counter(Dict2)
sum_cnt = cnt1 + cnt2
diff_cnt = cnt1 - cnt2
```