# how to find the same element in list of tuple and substitute it in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I have a list of tuple like this:

```
 t= [('A', 3000, '20140304'), ('B', 2000, '20140304'),('DD',3000, '20140304'), ('N', 102, '20140305'), ('S', 136, '20140305'), ('N', 182, '20140305'),('G',136, '20140305')]
```

I want to find if it has a same price on same date. If it does, return a new list of tuple pair with the name.The output should like this:

```
[('A','DD'),('S','G')]
```

Comment: Well then start with writing some code.

Comment: I tried using index and loop but doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can aggregate the tuples into a [defaultdict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900578/how-does-collections-defaultdict-work) with a tuple of `(price, date)` as the key. Iterate through that defaultdict, and return any list of names with more than one item.

```
from collections import defaultdict

price_date_dict = defaultdict(list)

for name, price, date in t:
    price_date_dict[(price, date)].append(name)

return [tuple(names) for names in price_date_dict.values() if len(names) > 1]
```

Comment: I think a `price_date_dict.items()` is needed

Comment: @JuniorCompressor Yes, that was incorrect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections as coll

t = [('A', 3000, '20140304'), ('B', 2000, '20140304'),('DD',3000, '20140304'), ('N', 102, '20140305'), ('S', 136, '20140305'), ('N', 182, '20140305'),('G',136, '20140305')]

d = coll.defaultdict(lambda:coll.defaultdict(set))
for a,p,stackOverflow in t: d[stackOverflow][p].add(a)

for t in d:
    for p in d[t]:
        print("On day", t, ", the following items were sold at price", p, ':\n' + ','.join(sorted(d[t][p])))
```