# Building a HashMap using Python in a loop. Clarification needed

Tags: python

I am running in a loop and and parsing a string. That string ultimately contains 2 items a host and application running on a host. As expected a host runs multiple applications. I'd like to store it all in one data structure where host is used as a key.

Below is my failed attempt. Please help me understand why only the last element is being saved in the host = app format.

```
What i expect to see
host = app1, app2 etc
What i see
Host = app2 (always last)


data = dict()

def add(line):
    l = line.split("/")
    host = l[0].strip()
    app = l[-1].strip()

    data[host].append(app)

for entry in env:
    if "/" not in entry: continue
    add(entry)

print data
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does collections.defaultdict work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900578/how-does-collections-defaultdict-work)

Comment: This would fail with a `KeyError`, not only return the last item. This REALLY needs a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `data[host].append(app)`

Would append the value of `app` to the list (or similar) stored as `data[host]`

When you run this, the value of `data[host]` is not set, and so you can't `append` to it. You will get a `KeyError`. Perhaps you meant `data[host] = app`? or...

```
try:
    data[host].append(app)
except KeyError:
    data[host] = [app]
```

Comment: Right. Tried that. This sets the last value in the list. If I iterate over 5 elements, only 5th one gets added

Comment: You can `try` to append to the list, and if that doesn't work start a new list.

Answer (score 0):

`data[host].append(app)`

You assume host is in the dict, which is not true for the first time you append to it.

Comment: This check causes an error     `if host in data:
        data[host].append(app)
    else:
        data[host]=app`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for. Thank you to all those trying to help

```
if host in data:
    data[host].append(app)
else:
    data[host] = [app]
```