# How to plot multiple signals in a single subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to plot one ore more signals into one plot.

For each signal, a individual color, linewidth and linestyle may be specified.
If multiple signals have to be plotted, a legend should be provided as well.

So far, I use the following code which allows me to plot up to three signals.

```
import matplotlib
fig = matplotlib.figure.Figure(figsize=(8,6))
subplot = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.2, 0.8, 0.75])
Signal2, Signal3, legend, t = None, None, None, None
Signal1, = subplot.plot(xDataSignal1, yDataSignal1, color=LineColor[0], linewidth=LineWidth[0],linestyle=LineStyle[0])
if (yDataSignal2 != [] and yDataSignal3 != []):
    Signal2, = subplot.plot(xDataSignal2, yDataSignal2, color=LineColor[1], linewidth=LineWidth[1],linestyle=LineStyle[1])
    Signal3, = subplot.plot(xDataSignal3, yDataSignal3, color=LineColor[2], linewidth=LineWidth[2],linestyle=LineStyle[2])
    legend = subplot.legend([Signal1, Signal2, Signal3], [yLabel[0], yLabel[1], yLabel[2]],LegendPosition,labelspacing=0.1, borderpad=0.1)
    legend.get_frame().set_linewidth(0.5)
    for t in legend.get_texts():
        t.set_fontsize(10)
elif (yDataSignal2 != []):
    Signal2, = subplot.plot(xDataSignal2, yDataSignal2, color=LineColor[1], linewidth=LineWidth[1],linestyle=LineStyle[1])
    legend = subplot.legend([Signal1, Signal2], [yLabel[0], yLabel[1]], LegendPosition,labelspacing=0.1, borderpad=0.1)
    legend.get_frame().set_linewidth(0.5)
    for t in legend.get_texts():
        t.set_fontsize(10)
```

Is it possible to generalize that code such that it is more Pythonic and supports up to n signals by still making use of matplotlib and subplot?

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: How about you create some kind of list of dict, where each element of the list is a dict which will have your x and y data, the linecolor, the linewidth, etc. Then you can just create a plot, iterate on said list of dict and plot everything the same axis?

Comment: Good remark. I will give this a try. Thx.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A list of dicts might be a good solution for this (you could even use a `defaultdict` to default the color and linewidth in case you don't want to specify it, read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900578/how-does-collections-defaultdict-work))

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

mysignals = [{'name': 'Signal1', 'x': np.arange(10,20,1),
             'y': np.random.rand(10), 'color':'r', 'linewidth':1},
            {'name': 'Signal2', 'x': np.arange(10,20,1),
             'y': np.random.rand(10), 'color':'b', 'linewidth':3},
            {'name': 'Signal3', 'x': np.arange(10,20,1),
             'y': np.random.rand(10), 'color':'k', 'linewidth':2}]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for signal in mysignals:
    ax.plot(signal['x'], signal['y'], 
            color=signal['color'], 
            linewidth=signal['linewidth'],
            label=signal['name'])

# Enable legend
ax.legend()
ax.set_title("My graph")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot.