# Concatenate values from the same first column in one line

Tags: python

I have a file like this:

```
A2ML1,ENST00000541459
A2ML1,ENST00000545692
A2ML1,ENST00000545850
A3GALT2,ENST00000442999
A4GALT,ENST00000249005
A4GALT,ENST00000381278
```

And I want to group the lines like this:

```
A2ML1,ENST00000541459,ENST00000545692,ENST00000545850
A3GALT2,ENST00000442999
A4GALT,ENST00000249005,ENST00000381278
```

Here is my code in python, that is leaving the file as original XD:

```
import sys

with open('gene_list.csv', 'r') as file_open:
    iterfile = iter(file_open)
    for line in iterfile:
        l = line.split(",")
        select = l[0]
        linext = iterfile.next()
        linext2 = linext.split(",")
        if select == linext2[0]:
            sys.stdout.write(select + ',' + linext2[1])
            next(file_open)
        else:
            sys.stdout.write(select + ',' + l[1])
```

I know that it is very easy to do but I am stuck with this. I really apreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: Could you not use a dictionary with the key being the value from the first column, and the value being a list?

Comment: Hi @Ben, that's a good idea but I have thousands of values. Maybe I should do a list of all values and iterate over them?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps :)

```
import csv
import collections

#Read in the data as a dictionary
with open('gene_list.csv', 'r') as fd:

    reader = csv.reader(fd)

    #If you have headers in the CSV file you want to skip
    #next(reader, None)

    #This dict will have key:value, value=list type
    unique_first_col = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for row in reader:
        unique_first_col[row[0]].append(row[1])

with open('output.csv', 'w') as fd:

    #Sorted dictionary
    sorted_d = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(unique_first_col.items()))
    for k, v in sorted_d.items():
        fd.write("%s, %s\n" % (k, ','.join(v)))
```

Notes:

- see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900578/how-does-collections-defaultdict-work) for `collections.defaultdict`
- See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) for information on CSV processing
- You may want to consider using simple string 'pre-processing' such as `strip()` before you key into the dictionary, as a trailing space may cause a key to be entered as a new key.
- See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key) for sorting dictionaries

Comment: using `collections.defaultdict(list)` would make things even simpler...

Comment: You're right! Thanks! I'm terrible at remembering the simple methods of doing things (there's so many)

Comment: Thank you very much @K.J.Phan! It worked! The only thing was that the first columns were not sorted as before, but all ok after using bash. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to try pandas you can do this way:-

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("gene_list.csv", header=None)
df.columns = ["First", "Second"]
df.groupby("First")["Second"].agg({"Second":lambda x:", ".join(x.astype(str))})
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to use the first value as a dictionary key. It is not strictly necessary to use defaultdict, but it makes constructing your list of secondary values easier.

```
from collections import defaultdict

merged = defaultdict(list)

with open('gene_list.csv', 'r') as f:
    for raw_line in f:
        line = raw_line.strip()
        first, second = line.split(',')
        merged[first].append(second)

for key, values in merged:
    print(key + ',' + ','.join(values))
```

If you have to assume that your original file can have more than two key, value pairs then you need to tweak this script a little.