# Add item to dictionary which has same value in list of dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to add a key `id` with the same `uuid.uuid4()` into the inner dictionary when 'node' values are equal and a new `uuid.uuid4()` when a distinct uuid is found.

Let's say 2 keys ('node' in this case) have same value like-> node: 'Bangalore', so I want to generate the same ID for it and a fresh ID for every other distinct node.

**This is the code I'm working on now:**

```
import uuid
import json

node_list = [
  {
    "nodes": [
      {
         "node": "Kunal",
         "label": "PERSON"
      },
      {
         "node": "Bangalore",
         "label": "LOC"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "nodes": [
      {
         "node": "John",
         "label": "PERSON"
      },
      {
         "node": "Bangalore",
         "label": "LOC"
      }
    ]
  }
]

for outer_node_dict in node_list:
      for inner_dict in outer_node_dict["nodes"]:
            inner_dict['id'] = str(uuid.uuid4()) # Remember the key's value here and apply this statement somehow?

print(json.dumps(node_list, indent = True))
```

---

**This is the response I want:**

```
"[
  {
    "nodes": [
      {
         "node": "Kunal",
         "label": "PERSON",
         "id": "fbf094eb-8670-4c31-a641-4cf16c3596d1"
      },
      {
         "node": "Bangalore",
         "label": "LOC",
         "id": "24867c2a-f66a-4370-8c5d-8af5b9a25675"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "nodes": [
      {
         "node": "John",
         "label": "PERSON",
         "id": "5eddc375-ed3e-4f6a-81dc-3966590e8f35"
      },
      {
         "node": "Bangalore",
         "label": "LOC",
         "id": "24867c2a-f66a-4370-8c5d-8af5b9a25675"
      }
    ]
  }
]"
```

---

**But currently its generating like this:**

```
"[
 {
  "nodes": [
   {
    "node": "Kunal",
    "label": "PERSON",
    "id": "3cce6e36-9d1c-4058-a11b-2bcd0da96c83"
   },
   {
    "node": "Bangalore",
    "label": "LOC",
    "id": "4d860d3b-1835-4816-a372-050c1cc88fbb"
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  "nodes": [
   {
    "node": "John",
    "label": "PERSON",
    "id": "67fc9ba9-b591-44d4-a0ae-70503cda9dfe"
   },
   {
    "node": "Bangalore",
    "label": "LOC",
    "id": "f83025a0-7d8e-4ec8-b4a0-0bced982825f"
   }
  ]
 }
]"
```

**How to remember key's value and apply the same ID for it in the dictionary?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want the `uuid` to be the same for the same "node" value. So, instead of generating it, store it to a dict

```
node_uuids = defaultdict(lambda: uuid.uuid4())
```

and then, in your inner loop, instead of

```
inner_dict['id'] = str(uuid.uuid4())
```

you write

```
inner_dict['id'] = node_uuids[inner_dict['node']]
```

A complete working example is as follows:

```
from collections import defaultdict

import uuid
import json

node_list = [
  {
    "nodes": [
      {
         "node": "Kunal",
         "label": "PERSON"
      },
      {
         "node": "Bangalore",
         "label": "LOC"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "nodes": [
      {
         "node": "John",
         "label": "PERSON"
      },
      {
         "node": "Bangalore",
         "label": "LOC"
      }
    ]
  }
]

node_uuids = defaultdict(lambda: uuid.uuid4())

for outer_node_dict in node_list:
      for inner_dict in outer_node_dict["nodes"]:
            inner_dict['id'] = str(node_uuids[inner_dict['node']])

print(json.dumps(node_list, indent = True))
```

Comment: `node_uuids = defaultdict(lambda: uuid.uuid4())` where does this fit in?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee - check out [how does defaultdict work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900578/how-does-collections-defaultdict-work) which should clear it up for you.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee: the `defaultdict` generates a new uuid if one is not already stored in it