# Flask - Why can I return a list, but not a dict?

Tags: python, flask

Lets say I have a basic flask program...

```
lis = [1, 2, 3, 4]
dict1 = defaultdict(list)
dict1["key"].append("Hello")

@app.route("/list/<string:index>")
def l(index):
    return lis[index]

@app.route("/dictionary/<string:key>")
def d(key):
    return dict1[key]
```

Why is the first valid, and the second invalid?

How do I return all of the items in the dictionary?

Comment: are you actually passing a variable `key` ? because `dict["key"]` and `dict[key]` are not the same. your error message should help too if you run with debug mode on. edit: Ah, i see your update now. alright.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that flask is expecting a simple string or callable object in the responses, as it requires passing the values around. A dictionary is not a callable object, and you have to convert it to a form flask can pass around using either `json.dumps` and setting the appropriate Content-type headers (`'application/json'` in this case) or just using `jsonify` that does the hard work for you. [Jsonify Docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.json.jsonify)

```
import flask
from flask import request, jsonify #import jsonify
from collections import defaultdict
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True


lis = [1, 2, 3, 4]
dict1 = defaultdict(list)
dict1.setdefault("key", []).append("Hello") #you do not need to setdefault if you're already using a defaultdict, but this does not raise any errors.
dict2 = {"a":"res"}

@app.route("/list/<string:index>")
def l(index):
    return lis[index]

@app.route("/dictionary/<string:key>")
def d(key):
    return jsonify(dict1[key]) #use it to handle dictionary

app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Dot not name your variable as `list` or `dict` as they shadow built ins. Try the code below. Link to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
lis = [1, 2, 3, 4]
dict1 = defaultdict(list)
dict1['key'].append("Hello")
```

If you want to get all the items of the dict1

```
dict1.items()
```

It contains a good explanation of how defaultdict works
[How does collections.defaultdict work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900578/how-does-collections-defaultdict-work)

Comment: I edited my example to more accurately reflect my program

Comment: still you are using in the wrong manner. check docs attached. Thanks

Comment: I still get the error: "TypeError: 'dict_items' object is not callable"

Comment: Also, I don't want to get all the items of dict1, just all of the values associated with the key that is passed in. Shouldn't I just be able to use: dict1['key']?

Comment: Your question and code are tangentials. yes you should get THE value from dict1['key'] but you have just one str object 'hello' mapped to the key so that should be returned.