# How to handle emty dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I am making a scraper with scrapy python 3. My script suppose to **scrape** a directory of companies.

Sometimes, scrapy don't find a field of item (the email or the website) because directory didn't publish these fields.

I am trying to handle this kind of exception, but as a newbie, it is complicated for me.

I tried to fix that with some "if". But my problem is to handle it in my pipeline.py file where I add the values in my MYSQL database.

This is my spider file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request
from ..items import ScrapingEntreprisesItem
from urlextract import URLExtract

class UsinedigitaleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'usinedigitale'
    allowed_domains = ['usine-digitale.fr']
    start_urls = ['https://www.usine-digitale.fr/annuaire-start-up/']

    def parse(self, response):

        urls = response.xpath("//a[@class='contenu']/@href").extract()

        for url in urls:
            absolute_url = response.urljoin(url)
            print('Voici absolute url :' + absolute_url)
            yield Request(absolute_url, callback=self.parse_startup)
        next_page = response.xpath("//a[@rel='next']/@href").extract_first().strip()
        absolute_next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page)
        yield Request(absolute_next_page_url)

    def parse_startup(self, response):
        items = ScrapingEntreprisesItem()

        startup_name = response.xpath("//h1/text()")
        startup_date_creation = response.xpath("//*[@itemprop='foundingDate']/@content")
        startup_website = response.xpath("//*[@id='infoPratiq']//a/@href")
        startup_email = response.xpath("//*[@itemprop='email']/text()")
        startup_address = response.xpath("//p[@itemprop='address']/text()")
        startup_founders = response.xpath("//*[@itemprop='founders']/p/text()")
        startup_market = response.xpath("//*[@id='ficheStartUp']/div[1]/article/div[6]/p")
        startup_description = response.xpath("//*[@itemprop='description']/p/text()")
        startup_short_description = response.xpath("//*[@itemprop='review']/p")

        if startup_name:
            items["startup_name"] = startup_name.extract()
        else:
            items["startup_name"] = ''

        if startup_date_creation:
            items["startup_date_creation"] = startup_date_creation.extract()
        else:
            items["startup_date_creation"] = ''

        if startup_website:
            startup_website = startup_website.extract()
            extractor = URLExtract()
            startup_website = extractor.find_urls(str(startup_website[0]))
            items["startup_website"] = startup_website
        else:
            items["startup_website"] = ''

        if startup_email:
            items["startup_email"] = startup_email.extract()
        else:
            items["startup_email"] = ''

        if startup_address:
            items["startup_address"] = startup_address.extract()
        else:
            items["startup_address"] = ''

        if startup_founders:
            items["startup_founders"] = startup_founders.extract()
        else:
            items["startup_founders"] = ''

        if startup_market:
            items["startup_market"] = startup_market.extract()
        else:
            items["startup_market"] = ''

        if startup_description:
            items["startup_description"] = startup_description.extract()
        else:
            items["startup_description"] = ''

        if startup_short_description:
            items["startup_short_description"] = startup_short_description.extract()
        else:
            items["startup_short_description"] = ''

        yield items
```

This is my pipelines.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import mysql.connector

# Define your item pipelines here
#
# Don't forget to add your pipeline to the ITEM_PIPELINES setting
# See: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html


class ScrapingEntreprisesPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.create_connection()

    def create_connection(self):
        self.conn=mysql.connector.connect(
            host = "mysql.com",
            port="3306",
            user = "username",
            password = "passpass",
            database='db123'
        )
        self.curr=self.conn.cursor()
        self.curr = self.conn.cursor(buffered=True)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        sql = "select * from entreprises where website = '" + item["startup_website"][0] + "' limit 1"
        print('sql : ' + sql)
        self.curr.execute(sql, multi=True)
        if self.curr.rowcount == 1:
            print("Entreprise found")
        else:
            print("Entreprise NOT found")

            self.curr.execute("""insert into entreprises values (default,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s )""",(
                str(item["startup_name"][0]),
                str(item["startup_date_creation"][0]),
                str(item["startup_website"][0]),
                str(item["startup_email"][0]),
                str(item["startup_address"][0]),
                str(item["startup_founders"][0]),
                str(item["startup_market"][0]),
                str(item["startup_description"][0]),
                str(item["startup_short_description"][0])
            ))
            self.conn.commit()
            print("DB mise à jour!!!")
            return item
```

And this is my items.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Define here the models for your scraped items
#
# See documentation in:
# https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html

import scrapy


class ScrapingEntreprisesItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    startup_name = scrapy.Field()
    startup_date_creation = scrapy.Field()
    startup_website = scrapy.Field()
    startup_email = scrapy.Field()
    startup_address = scrapy.Field()
    startup_founders = scrapy.Field()
    startup_market = scrapy.Field()
    startup_description = scrapy.Field()
    startup_short_description = scrapy.Field()
```

So I get several issues:
Or I get some Keyerror
or I get some List error
or it is mysql which can't add dictionary in a text field.

Also my scraper is stopping after hundreds of requests whereas there are thousands of urls to **scrape**. But this is another topic (just in case you see the reason why).

Thanks in advance for trying to help me.

Comment: Maybe you want to try default dict https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900578/how-does-collections-defaultdict-work

Comment: A [mre] would be really helpful.

Comment: Thans for suggesting this idea. The problem is my dictionary are created with scrapy. And I am not good enough to implement this kind of solution. :-(

Comment: Well...@wovano... the only way to reproduce this issue is to create a new scrapy project and copy paste these 3 files in your project and then run the spider. You'll see the issue.

Comment: By removing the [0], it works but I get the bracklets added in my mysql columns... :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways in scrapy to use default values.
The most simple one is just using a structure like this:

```
items["startup_name"] = startup_name.get() or ''
# .get() will return first value or None if selector is not exists.
```

Overall this code will look better:

```
    def parse_startup(self, response):
        item = ScrapingEntreprisesItem()

        item['startup_name'] = response.css("h1::text").get() or ''
        item['startup_date_creation'] = response.xpath("//*[@itemprop='foundingDate']/@content").get() or ''
        item['startup_website'] = response.css("#infoPratiq a::attr(href)").get() or ''
...
# And so on...
```

You can also use [Scrapy item loaders](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html), it's a little more complicated, but will allow you to add more flexibility to your pipeline..

Comment: Thank you so much @Michael Savchenko