# Python: Create a dictionary where keys have multiple values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

The problem that I have is hard to explain, easy to understand:

I have a list of tuples:

```
L=[('a','111'),('b','222'),('a','333'),('b','444')]
```

from this list I want to createa dictionary where the keys are the first elements of the tuples ('a' and 'b') and the values associated are in a list:

expected output:

```
{'a':['111','333'],'b':['222','444']}
```

How can I solve this problem?

```
d={}
for x in range (len(L)):
    d[L[x][0]]=[L[x][1]]
return d
```

but as you can easy understand, the output won't be complete since the list will show just the last value associated to that key in L

Comment: This exact problems is solved in one of the examples for `collections.defaultdict`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to set the key in the dict the first time. Then append your value:

```
L=[('a','111'),('b','222'),('a','333'),('b','444')]

d = {}
for key, value in L:
    d.setdefault(key, []).append(value)

print(d)
# {'a': ['111', '333'], 'b': ['222', '444']}
```

Comment: Defaultdicts mostly replaced the need for `setdefault` in my experience but this is the way to go if you want to stick to core dicts.

Answer (score 2):

You have to append `L[x][1]` to an existing list, not replace whatever was there with a new singleton list.

```
d={}
for x in range (len(L)):
    if L[x][0] not in d:
        d[L[x][0]] = []
    d[L[x][0]].append(L[x][1])
return d
```

A `defaultdict` makes this easier:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for x in range(len(L)):
    d[L[x][0]].append(L[x][1])
return d
```

A more idiomatic style of writing this would be to iterate directly over the `list` and unpack the key and value immediately:

```
d = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in L:
    d[key].append(value)
```

Comment: there is no way to remove the 'defaultdict(<class 'list'>,' from the output?

Comment: You can create a regular dict with `d = dict(d)` once you are done, but typically you don't care about what the string representation of the object itself is.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
L = [('a','111'),('b','222'),('a','333'),('b','444')]
my_dict = {}

for item in L:
    if item[0] not in my_dict:
        my_dict[item[0]] = []

    my_dict[item[0]].append(item[1])

print(my_dict)
```

Output:

```
python your_script.py
{'a': ['111', '333'], 'b': ['222', '444']}
```

As pointed by @chepner, you can use [defaultdict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900578/how-does-collections-defaultdict-work) to.

Basically, with `defaultdict` you'll not need to check if there is no key yet in your `dict`.

So it would be:

```
L = [('a','111'),('b','222'),('a','333'),('b','444')]
my_dict = defaultdict(list)

for item in L:
    my_dict[item[0]].append(item[1])

print(my_dict)
```

And the output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'a': ['111', '333'], 'b': ['222', '444']})
```

And if you want to get a `dict` from the `defaultdict`, you can simply create a new dict from it:

```
print(dict(my_dict))
```

And the output will be:

```
{'a': ['111', '333'], 'b': ['222', '444']}
```

Comment: there is no way to remove ('defaultdict(<class 'list'>))' from the output?

Comment: yes, there is. You can simply create a new dict from it: print(dict(my_dict))