# Converting file into dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have an txt file listing name and age:

```
John,20
Mary,14
Kevin,60
Mary,15
John,40
```

And trying to write the below function to return a dictionary:

```
def read(filename):
    results = {}
    with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'data.txt')) as file:
        for line in file:
            location,value = line.split(',', 1)
            results[location] = value
        print(results)
```

I'm trying to format as:

```
{'John': [20, 40], 'Mary': [14, 15], 'Kevin': [60]}
```

But currently getting:

```
{'John': '20', 'Mary': '15\n', 'Kevin': '60\n'}
```

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: instead of this line  `results[location] = value` you need to put if statment, and check whether location key already exists. if yes, append new value. if not `results[location] = [value]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to test if the key is in the dictionary, if not add an empty list.
Add the current value to the list at the key:

```
def read(filename):
    results = {}
    with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'data.txt')) as file:
        for line in file:
            if line.strip():     # guard against empty lines
                location,value = line.strip().split(',', 1)  # get rid of \n
                if location not in results:
                    results[location] = []
                results[location].append( int(value) )  # as number
        print(results)
```

You can lookup `dict.setdefault(key,defaultvalue)` and `collections.defaultdict` to get more performance if needed - f.e. here: [How does collections.defaultdict work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900578/how-does-collections-defaultdict-work)

Answer (score 1):

You can try defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def read(filename):
results = deafultdict(list)
with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'data.txt')) as file:
    for line in file:
        location,value = line.split(',', 1)
        results[location].append(value.replace("\n", ""))
```

You will get:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'John': ['20', '40'], 'Mary': ['14', '15'], 'Kevin': ['60']})
```