# Aggregation for unique values in Python

Tags: python, oop

I have a csv file. I want to make an aggregation operation on this. My aim is printing the daily number of unique measurements in descending order based on dates.

.csv file looks like this:

```
['endDate,weight\n',
 ' 2020-06-12  00:00:00+03:00 , 91.5,91.9,91.9,91.9,92.55,92.55,92.55,92.55,92.1,92.1,93.3,93.3 \n',
 ' 2020-06-13  00:00:00+03:00 , 91.6,91.6,92.85,92.85,92.85,92.85,92.3,92.3,92.1,92.1,94.1,94.1 \n',
 ' 2020-06-14  00:00:00+03:00 , 91.5,91.5,91.65,91.65,91.5,91.5,92.9,92.9 \n',
 ' 2020-06-15  00:00:00+03:00 , 91.85,91.85,91.6,91.6,91.85,91.85,92.55,92.55,92.4,92.4,93.7,93.7,93.35,93.35 \n',
 ' 2020-06-16  00:00:00+03:00 , 91.6,91.6,91.3,91.3,92.75,92.75,92.15,92.15,93.15,93.15,92.9,92.9 \n',
 ' 2020-06-17  00:00:00+03:00 , 91.05,91.05,91.85,91.85,92.4,92.4,92.4,92.4,94.0,94.0,93.7,93.7,93.05,93.05,93.05,93.05 \n',
 ' 2020-06-18  00:00:00+03:00 , 91.55,91.55,91.45,91.45,91.25,91.25,91.65,92.2,91.95 \n',
 ' 2020-06-19  00:00:00+03:00 , 91.3,91.6,92.45,92.05,91.8,93.1,92.7,93.5,93.15 \n',
 ' 2020-06-20  00:00:00+03:00 , 90.8,90.8,90.6,90.6,90.6,90.6,92.15,92.15,92.05,92.05,91.4,91.4 \n',
 ' 2020-06-21  00:00:00+03:00 ,\n']
```

Expecting result is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtwFy.png)

```
import re
import collections

with open("weights.csv") as myFile:
    formattedData = dict()
    for line in myFile:
        try:
            date , numbers = line.split(' , ')
            numbers = numbers.replace("\n","") 
            numbers = numbers.split(',')
            formattedData[date] = len(list(set(numbers)))
        except:
            date = line
            formattedData[date]=0

formattedData
```

After splitting data, my data looks like this:

```
{'endDate,weight\n': 0,
 ' 2020-06-12  00:00:00+03:00 , 91.5,91.9,91.9,91.9,92.55,92.55,92.55,92.55,92.1,92.1,93.3,93.3 \n': 0,
 ' 2020-06-13  00:00:00+03:00 , 91.6,91.6,92.85,92.85,92.85,92.85,92.3,92.3,92.1,92.1,94.1,94.1 \n': 0,
 ' 2020-06-14  00:00:00+03:00 , 91.5,91.5,91.65,91.65,91.5,91.5,92.9,92.9 \n': 0,
 ' 2020-06-15  00:00:00+03:00 , 91.85,91.85,91.6,91.6,91.85,91.85,92.55,92.55,92.4,92.4,93.7,93.7,93.35,93.35 \n': 0,
 ' 2020-06-16  00:00:00+03:00 , 91.6,91.6,91.3,91.3,92.75,92.75,92.15,92.15,93.15,93.15,92.9,92.9 \n': 0,
 ' 2020-06-17  00:00:00+03:00 , 91.05,91.05,91.85,91.85,92.4,92.4,92.4,92.4,94.0,94.0,93.7,93.7,93.05,93.05,93.05,93.05 \n': 0,
 ' 2020-06-18  00:00:00+03:00 , 91.55,91.55,91.45,91.45,91.25,91.25,91.65,92.2,91.95 \n': 0,
 ' 2020-06-19  00:00:00+03:00 , 91.3,91.6,92.45,92.05,91.8,93.1,92.7,93.5,93.15 \n': 0,
 ' 2020-06-20  00:00:00+03:00 , 90.8,90.8,90.6,90.6,90.6,90.6,92.15,92.15,92.05,92.05,91.4,91.4 \n': 0,
 ' 2020-06-21  00:00:00+03:00 ,\n': 0}
```

c=Counter(formattedData)

Comment: I have added how it looks.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with your source list of strings as input. [PythonFiddle](http://pythonfiddle.com/). Do you have the same as a result after reading the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [defaultdict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900578/how-does-collections-defaultdict-work).
Replace `formattedData = dict()` with

```
formattedData = defaultdict(int)
```

Replace `formattedData[date] = len(list(set(numbers)))` with

```
formattedData[date] += len(set(numbers))
```

Finally, create a new dictionary with keys [sorted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value) in descending order of count:

```
descending = {dt: count for dt, count in sorted(formattedData.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)}
print(descending)
```

Comment: Thank you, actually I want to count each unique value for each date.

Comment: Doesn't the above code produce the result you mentioned in "Expecting result" image?