# hash_table initialisation, what is happening?

Tags: python, hashtable

I have a quick question about the below code regarding hash tables. For line 5- what is happening? So we initialised 'hash_table' to be a dictionary. Then for each element 'i' in nums we do hash_table[i]?? But the hash_table is empty- since just initialised it? This is where I am confused.
Is it correct to say that we are defining the keys by doing hash_table['i']? If this is the case, why +=1?
(P.S. nums is a list of integers shall we say)

```
class Solution:
    def singleNumber(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        hash_table = defaultdict(int)
        for i in nums:
            hash_table[i] += 1

        for i in hash_table:
            if hash_table[i] == 1:
               return i
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does collections.defaultdict work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900578/how-does-collections-defaultdict-work)

Comment: Who chose that name? It's not really a `hash_table`, rather a simple counter...

Comment: Be aware that ``collections.Counter`` might be more suitable for this use-case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your understanding of the `defaultdict` is correct: If the key is not present, then the key will be added with a default value. In the case of a `defaultdict(int)`, that default value will be 0. But what are you passing as `nums`? If `nums` is not empty then `hash_table` will not be empty after the first `for` loop. However, method `singleNumber` just returns a single value, which will be the first key of `hash_table` that appeared in the `nums` list only once. As Tomericlo pointed out, your `hash_table` is acting more like a set of counters counting the number of times that each distinct integer in `nums` appears. I have modified your code to insert a `print` statement (and missing `import` statements) and added a test case.

Note that if no integer in `nums` appears only once, then your code never finds a match and never issues a `return` statement, which is equivalent to returning the value `None`.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from typing import List


class Solution:
    def singleNumber(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        hash_table = defaultdict(int)
        for i in nums:
            hash_table[i] += 1

        print(hash_table) # added statement

        for i in hash_table:
            if hash_table[i] == 1:
               return i

# test case:  
solution = Solution()
print(solution.singleNumber([7, 6, 7, 12]))
```

Prints:

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {7: 2, 6: 1, 12: 1})
6
```

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question which is how come we can do `hash_table[i] += 1` if at that point in time `hash_table` is still empty and doesn't have a key `i`...

Comment: Also it doesn't return the first key, it returns the first number that appeared only once in the list

Comment: @Tomerikoo Perhaps. But the OP's code seems to be looking for a value of `1` after doing `hash_table[i] += 1`, from which I infer they expected a default value of 0 to have been added. Moreover, the OP asks, 'Why is my hash_table empty?", which I take to be the actual question. I have updated my answer anyway,

Comment: The dict acts as a simple counter... Each number in the list does `+= 1` to the corresponding key. In the end, doing `if hash_table[i] == 1:` means that key appeared only once in the original list. Try as input `[7, 7, 6, 6, 12]`

Comment: @Tomericlo You are correct. I was assuming that each number in `nums` was distinct. Thanks.