# Why does the KeyError pop up and how to prevent it

Tags: python, dictionary, keyerror

Overall, I have a code which reads through a data file with data about countries which participated in the Olympics. This portion of code checks if in the year requested there are medallists from any countries and writes it in the dict if there are any. Basically, I am trying to count the amount of Gold, Silver and Bronze medals for each country in this year. That's why I've made a dictionary however for some reason "KeyError: 'Norway'" occurs, and I'm unsure how to fix that.

A bit more info: **medals_dict** is an empty dictionary. There is no dictionary **full_country**, **full_country** is just a text string

Here's the code:

```
    def total_medal_counter(year_in_data, full_country, medal):
    global year
    global medals_dict
    if year == year_in_data:
        if full_country in medals_dict:
            if medal in full_country:
                medals_dict[full_country][medal] = medals_dict[full_country][medal] + 1
                print(medals_dict)
        else:
            medals_dict[full_country][medal] = 1
            print(medals_dict)
```

Comment: Whenever you find yourself doing `if key in dict: dict[key] += 1 else: dict[key] = 0`, you can use [`defaultdict(int)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900578/how-does-collections-defaultdict-work). Same for creating new lists, sets, or any type of object when the key doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

You are checking

```
if full_country in medals_dict:
```

but have

```
else:
        medals_dict[full_country][medal] = 1
```

So when you come to that else statement, you are accessing `medals_dict[full_country]` without it existing, since you have never created that entry. You probably wanted

```
else:
    medals_dict[full_country] = {medal: 1}
```

Your inner `if` is also probably supposed to be

```
if medal in medals_dict[full_country]:
```

Full code:

```
def total_medal_counter(year_in_data, full_country, medal):
    global year
    global medals_dict
    if year == year_in_data:
        if full_country in medals_dict:
            if medal in medals_dict[full_country]:
                medals_dict[full_country][medal] = medals_dict[full_country][medal] + 1
                print(medals_dict)
        else:
            medals_dict[full_country] = {medal: 1}
            print(medals_dict)
```

Comment: @Reti43 true, good suggestion