# Number of values in a specific dictionary key

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to get the count of values for a specific key in dictionary.

`len(synonyms[word])` just gives me the length of the word I have added to the dictionary and not the value count for the key.

This is my attempt:

```
synonyms = {}

while True:
command = input()

if command == "add":
    first_word = input()
    second_word = input()
    synonyms[second_word] = first_word
    synonyms[first_word] = second_word

elif command == "count":
    word = input()
    print(len(synonyms[word]))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are doing and what you want to do. Could you please modify your code to make it a [mre]? In particular, avoid using `input()` when posting code on stackoverflow. Instead, include the input as hardcoded data in your post, so that we can see exactly what input you're running your code on.

Comment: With "count of values", do you mean how many values are attached to a specific key? Because with a dictionary, there will always be one entry per key.

Comment: @Kroshtan it looks like OP is expecting for multiple assignments to a key to be added as a `list` but without any actual `input` or clarification, it's hard to tell without guessing.

Comment: The input I'm running is in the "output" image. Command  "add" -> input "Eriks" -> input "Zilais" -> command "count" -> input the key you wan't to get the values count of "Eriks". So the count command + input of the key "Eriks" should return me "1", because in that key there is only one value.

Comment: @Muffin every key will always have one value for a `dict` unless its value is a `list`. See the answer @Stef posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to build a dictionary that maps words to lists of words. But that's not what your current code is doing. Instead, your current code is building a dictionary that maps words to words. The problem is on that line:

```py
synonyms[second_word] = first_word
```

On that line, if there is already an entry for `second_word`, then this entry is erased and replaced with `first_word`. That means that all previous synonyms are lost, and only the last synonym is kept.

Instead, you should explicitly use lists and `.append`. Here are two ways to fix the line `synonyms[second_word] = first_word`:

```py
# FIRST WAY
if second_word not in synonyms:
    synonyms[second_word] = [first_word]  # create new list with one element
else:
    synonyms[second_word].append(first_word)  # add one element to existing list

# SECOND WAY
synonyms.setdefault(second_word, []).append(first_word)  # create new empty list if necessary, and add one element to the list
```

Finally we get the following code. I chose to use the second way, because it's shorter. But the two ways are equivalent and only a matter of personal taste.

```py
synonyms = {}

while True:
    command = input().strip()
    if command == "add":
        first_word = input().strip()
        second_word = input().strip()
        synonyms.setdefault(second_word, []).append(first_word)
        synonyms.setdefault(first_word, []).append(second_word)
    elif command == "count":
        word = input().strip()
        print(len(synonyms[word]))
```

Two small notes I'd like to add:

- Instead of using the `.setdefault` method of `dict`, there is a third way which is to use `collections.defaultdict` instead of `dict`. If you're interested, you can read [the documentation on `defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), or this stackoverflow question: [How does collections.defaultdict work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900578/how-does-collections-defaultdict-work).
- I added `.strip()` after every call to `input()`. This is because the string returned by `input()` usually ends with a newline character, which is annoying, since you might end with `'add\n'` instead of `'add'`. String method `.strip()` removes all whitespace characters (spaces, tabs and newlines) at the beginning and the end of the string

Comment: Oh, right, lol. Sorry that it was that hard to understand what I want to produce here, but you got it all right. Thank you, worked like a charm! :)

Comment: @Muffin It wasn't really that hard to understand, because the problem was simple. But using `input()` makes it more annoying to reproduce your issue, so I strongly suggest you try to avoid it the next time you ask a question. You're more likely to receive an answer if it's easy to reproduce your issue. For instance, you could write: `hardcoded_input = iter('add king monarch add queen monarch count king count monarch'.split())` then replace every `input().strip()` with `next(hardcoded_input)`.