# How do I count reoccuring values in excel with python?

Tags: python, dataframe

So I've made a survey where I have a bunch of questions.
I now want to analyze the answers with python.
The answers for this question are:

| meetbare_factoren_klimaat |
| --- |
| Beschermen van ecosystemen;CO2-uitstoot;Mate van toegang tot betaalbare en duurzame energie voor iedereen |
| Beschermen van ecosystemen;Beschermen van biodiversiteit;CO2-uitstoot;Methaan (CH4)-uitstoot;Lachgas of distikstofoxide (N2O)-uitstoot;Belasting van de grond door stikstof en fosfor;Fijnstof in de lucht |
| Beschermen van ecosystemen;Beschermen van bossen;Beschermen van biodiversiteit;CO2-uitstoot;Gaten in de ozonlaag;Fijnstof in de lucht |
| Beschermen van ecosystemen;Beschermen van bossen;Beschermen van biodiversiteit;Mate van toegang tot betaalbare en duurzame energie voor iedereen |
| Beschermen van bossen;Beschermen van biodiversiteit;Fijnstof in de lucht |
| Beschermen van bossen;CO2-uitstoot;Fijnstof in de lucht |
| Beschermen van ecosystemen;Beschermen van bossen;Beschermen van biodiversiteit;CO2-uitstoot;Methaan (CH4)-uitstoot;Mate van toegang tot betaalbare en duurzame energie voor iedereen |
| Beschermen van ecosystemen;Beschermen van biodiversiteit;CO2-uitstoot;Fijnstof in de lucht |
| Beschermen van ecosystemen;Beschermen van bossen;Beschermen van biodiversiteit;CO2-uitstoot;Methaan (CH4)-uitstoot;Lachgas of distikstofoxide (N2O)-uitstoot;Ozon (O3)-uitstoot;Fluorgassen-uitstoot;Gaten in de ozonlaag;Belasting van de grond door stikstof en fosfor;Fijnstof in de lucht;Mate van toegang tot betaalbare en duurzame energie voor iedereen;Effect op menselijke gezondenheid |
| Beschermen van ecosystemen;Beschermen van bossen;Beschermen van biodiversiteit;CO2-uitstoot;Methaan (CH4)-uitstoot;Lachgas of distikstofoxide (N2O)-uitstoot;Ozon (O3)-uitstoot;Fluorgassen-uitstoot;Gaten in de ozonlaag;Belasting van de grond door stikstof en fosfor;Fijnstof in de lucht |
| Beschermen van ecosystemen;Beschermen van bossen;Beschermen van biodiversiteit;CO2-uitstoot |
| Beschermen van bossen;Beschermen van biodiversiteit;Mate van toegang tot betaalbare en duurzame energie voor iedereen |

With this question, you can choose multiple of the given options, and suggest your own option(s).

I can make different lists of the chosen answers in a for loop, by using `split(;)` (The different options are separated with a ";").

**I need my output to look something like this:**

Beschermen van ecosystemen: 6 times (60%)

Beschermen van bossen: 4 times (30%)

Beschermen van biodiversiteit: 3 times (20%)

CO2-uitstoot: 0 times (0%)

Methaan (CH4)-uitstoot: 10 times (80%)

Lachgas of distikstofoxide (N2O)-uitstoot: 5 times (50%)

So I need to count the amount of times specific values are present in my data.

I've tried many things by now and I just can't figure it out.

**This was my first attempt (more elifs needed for all the values, the values here are different, but that doesn't matter):**

```
finan_sit_count = 0
ver_twe_recht_pol_count = 0
onv_count = 0
soc_cont_count = 0

for row in range(2, 12):
    char = "T"
    factoren_list = ws[char + str(row)].value.split(";")
    if "Tevredenheid met financiële situatie" in factoren_list:
        finan_sit_count += 1
    elif "Vertrouwen in tweede kamer, rechters en politie" in factoren_list:
        ver_twe_recht_pol_count += 1
    elif "Mate van onveiligheidsgevoelens" in factoren_list:
        onv_count += 1
    elif "Tevredenheid met sociale contacten" in factoren_list:
        soc_cont_count += 1

print("\nTevredenheid met financiële situatie: " + str(finan_sit_count))
print("Tevredenheid met financiële situatie in %: " +
      cnvt_to_procent_string(finan_sit_count, 12, 0))

print("\nVertrouwen in tweede kamer, rechters en politie: " +
      str(ver_twe_recht_pol_count))
print("Vertrouwen in tweede kamer, rechters en politie in %: " +
      cnvt_to_procent_string(ver_twe_recht_pol_count, 12, 0))

print("\nMate van onveiligheidsgevoelens: " + str(onv_count))
print("Mate van onveiligheidsgevoelens in %: " +
      cnvt_to_procent_string(onv_count, 12, 0))

print("\nTevredenheid met sociale contacten: " + str(soc_cont_count))
print("Tevredenheid met sociale contacten in %: " +
      cnvt_to_procent_string(soc_cont_count, 12, 0))
```

I thought this would work, although it looks not really that efficient, but it didn't count everything.

**After that I've tried many things. One that I ended up almost getting to work was using the `Counting()` function.**

```
for row in range(2, 12):
    char = "T"
    factoren_list = ws[char + str(row)].value.split(";")
    print("\n Factoren list" + str(row) + ":")
    print(factoren_list)
    result = list(Counter(factoren_list).items())
    print("\n Result" + str(row) + ":")
    print(result)
    factoren.update(result)
print("\n Factoren: ")
print(factoren)
```

The problem with using update is that it doesn't add the amounts together, so the maximum value of something will always be 1.

I need help with this very badly. It seems very simple to fix, and I really need an solution for this.
Can somebody please help me out?

Comment: Welcome to SO. If I understood correctly what you want, the problem is the elif. When you put an if-elif logic, either none or one option gets executed, but never both. It seems to me that you need multiple (independent) ifs.

Comment: Say ```a = "X"```. ```if a == "X": do something``` followed by ```elif a == "Z": do other stuff```. You won't do other stuff, because the condition in the if was True.

Comment: @fdireito Maybe if just that simple. I'll check if that works right now.

Comment: Look at from collections import defaultdict. In your code answers = defaultdict(int). Each answer will be a key and count will be the value. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900578/how-does-collections-defaultdict-work

Comment: @fdireito that does look like it helped, but it still gives me wrong answers, and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will be very difficult to maintain (when adding new values, etc.) with all the strings hard-coded into the if statements and then repeated later in the print statements, so I'd begin by storing these in a list that you can iterate over.

```
phrases_to_search = [
    "Tevredenheid met financiële situatie",
    "Vertrouwen in tweede kamer, rechters en politie"
    "Mate van onveiligheidsgevoelens",
    "Tevredenheid met sociale contacten",
]
```

I'd then combine all the phrases you are searching over into a single list to  make the search easier. Something like:

```
char = "T"
row_range = range(2, 12)
all_responses = [ response for row in row_range for response in ws[char + str(row)].value.split(";") ]
```

You can then get all the counts using a single dictionary expression:

```
response_counts = {p: all_responses.count(p) for p in phrases_to_search}
```

and print the results with something like:

```
for r, count in response_counts.keys():
    print(r, ":", count)
```

I've omitted the bit where you print the percentages but I'm sure you can work that out.

Comment: Your solution looks extremely promising and elegant. Should I keep my for loop that I had, or is that not needed, because vscode is now saying that 'char' and 'response' aren't defined

Comment: Apologies, I think I missed a part. You should define `char` and `row_range`, but not `response` as that is defined within the list comprehension. I have edited the code above accordingly. Hope it works for you!

Comment: Thanks for helping. However, it still gives me an error:  https://imgur.com/a/S0cjz89

Comment: Apologies, the dictionary comprehension part should be `response_counts = {p: all_responses.count(p) for p in phrases_to_search}`. Have edited above.