# Check if a function is a method of some object

Tags: python, function, methods

How to check if a function is a method of some object?

For example:

```
def check_method(f):
    ...

check_method(lambda x: x + 1)           # >>> False
check_method(SomeClass().some_method)  # >>> True
```

There are some special attributes in methods in my 'helloworld' example (e.g. 'im_self', '__self__' etc).  Can I rely on them or there is some nicer way?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use [`inspect.ismethod()`](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.ismethod).

The documentation states:

> Return true if the object is a bound method written in Python.

This means that it will work as you intend for classes that you define in Python. However, for methods of built-in classes like `list` or classes implemented in extension modules it will return `False`.

Comment: Note that you must pass in a method of an instance for this and `types.MethodType` to work. Not method of the class. For example: `SomeClass.some_method` will evaluate to `False`. And during the definition of the class, this is not possible.

Answer (score 7):

It is also possible to check against the types defined in the built in [types library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html):

```
import types
isinstance(obj.method, types.MethodType) # True
```

Comment: Note: this only works in py3 for *bound* methods, since in py3 there is no such thing as an unbound method anymore, it will just be a function.   It does work in py2 for both cases however.

Answer (score 3):

A twist to the question involves asking to check if some function *name* would be available as a method. Since duck typing is considered pythonic there should be a simple

```
hasmethod(obj, 'some_method')
```

but it seems, there isn't.

Duck typing seems to be best done by just trying:

```
try:
  obj.some_method()
except:
  # try something else
```

If someone wants a function to check programmatically if an object has a method with a certain variable name, then the following function has been mentioned:

```
def hasmethod(obj, method_name):
  return hasattr(obj, method_name) and callable(getattr(obj, method_name))
```

But for Python 3 and 3.1 at least you need to get callable() back which was removed. A discussion of the want of bringing it back can be found [in a python bug entry](http://bugs.python.org/issue10518)
Resurrect callable with e.g.:

```
def callable(obj):
    return isinstance(obj, collections.Callable)
```

This is straight from the above mentioned python bugtracker. 
Other [sources on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234/what-is-a-callable-in-python/115349#115349) mention

```
callable = lambda o: hasattr(o, '__call__') or isinstance(o, collections.Callable)
```

which adds the hasattr to the call.
Both work fine in my use case

```
>>> bstr = b'spam'
>>> str = 'eggs'
>>> hasmethod(str, 'decode')
False
>>> hasmethod(bstr, 'decode')
True
```

For more details look at the already cited [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111234/923794)

Comment: The righter way to resurrect `callable` in Python 3.0 and 3.1 was to access the underlying function through `ctypes`: `bool(ctypes.pythonapi.PyCallable_Check(ctypes.py_object(obj)))`. Incidentally I made a Python library years ago to do that: https://pypi.org/project/ctypes-callable