# How can I do to test if a variable is a type 'method'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to check the type of my variable `user`. When I do that :

```
print(typ(user))
```

I got that `<class 'method'>`

But now I would like to check the type of the variable user.

So I did that :

```
if type(user) == 'method':
    # my code
```

But it doesn't work, the type 'method' is not knownn by Python ... I don't know why.

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: The type is "class" the instance is "method"

Comment: Use `isinstance(user, method)` instead of `type(user) == '...'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a function is a method of some object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963729/check-if-a-function-is-a-method-of-some-object)