# Python Suite, Package, Module, TestCase and TestSuite differences

Tags: python, unit-testing, package, suite

Best Guess:

- method - def(self, maybeSomeVariables); lines of code which achieve some purpose
- Function - same as method but returns something
- Class - group of methods/functions
- Module - a script, OR one or more classes. Basically a .py file.
- Package - a folder which has modules in, and also a __init__.py file in there.
- Suite - Just a word that gets thrown around a lot, by convention
- TestCase - unittest's equivalent of a function
- TestSuite - unittest's equivalent of a Class (or Module?)

My question is: Is this completely correct, and did I miss any hierarchical building blocks from that list?

Comment: Edit: I should have emphasised the question was more about (title); the notes about method, function and class were quick and brief to give scope - not intended to be the main focus of the answer! =)

So in terms of big fish eaten by bigger fish: method/function/TestCase is usually in Class/TestSuite, which are usually in Module/TestSuite, which are usually in a Package

Comment: I guess that sums up the usual case. The point of the long answer was to make it clear that there isn't hierarchy of objects. Objects are just objects and you can turn the hierarchy on its head if you want (subject to what the types allow). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel that you're putting in differences that don't actually exist. There isn't really a hierarchy as such. In python *everything* is an object. This isn't some abstract notion, but quite fundamental to how you should think about constructs you create when using python. An object is just a bunch of other objects. There is a slight subtlety in whether you're using [new-style classes](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/) or not, but in the absence of a good reason otherwise, just use and assume new-style classes. Everything below is assuming new-style classes.

If an object is [callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234/what-is-a-callable-in-python), you can call it using the calling syntax of a pair of braces, with the arguments inside them: `my_callable(arg1, arg2)`. To be callable, an object needs to implement the `__call__` method (or else have the correct field set in its C level type definition).

In python an object has a `type` associated with it. The type describes how the object was constructed. So, for example, a list object is of type `list` and a function object is of type `function`. The types themselves are of type `type`. You can find the type by using the built-in function `type()`. A list of all the built-in types can be found in the python [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html). Types are actually callable objects, and are used to create instances of a given type.

Right, now that's established, the nature of a given object is defined by it's type. This describes the objects of which it comprises. Coming back to your questions then:

Firstly, the bunch of objects that make up some object are called the attributes of that object. These attributes can be anything, but they typically consist of methods and some way of storing state (which might be types such as `int` or `list`).

A [function](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#functions) is an object of type `function`. Crucially, that means it has the `__call__` method as an attribute which makes it a callable (the `__call__` method is also an object that itself has the `__call__` method. It's `__call__` all the way down ;)

A [class](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#classes-and-class-instances), in the python world, can be considered as a type, but typically is used to refer to types that are not built-in. These objects are used to create other objects. You can define your own classes with the class keyword, and to create a class which is new-style you must inherit from `object` (or some other new-style class). When you inherit, you create a type that acquires all the characteristics of the parent type, and then you can overwrite the bits you want to (and you *can* overwrite any bits you want!). When you instantiate a class (or more generally, a type) by calling it, another object is returned which is created by that class (how the returned object is created can be changed in weird and crazy ways by modifying the class object).

A [method](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#methods) is a special type of function that is called using the attribute notation. That is, when it is created, 2 extra attributes are added to the method (remember it's an object!) called `im_self` and `im_func`. `im_self` I will describe in a few sentences. `im_func` is a function that implements the method. When the method is called, like, for example, `foo.my_method(10)`, this is equivalent to calling `foo.my_method.im_func(im_self, 10)`. This is why, when you define a method, you define it with the extra first argument which you apparently don't seem to use (as `self`).

When you write a bunch of methods when defining a class, these become *unbound* methods. When you create an instance of that class, those methods become *bound*. When you call an bound method, the `im_self` argument is added for you as the object in which the bound method resides. You can still call the unbound method of the class, but you need to explicitly add the class instance as the first argument:

```
class Foo(object):

    def bar(self):
        print self
        print self.bar
        print self.bar.im_self # prints the same as self
```

We can show what happens when we call the various manifestations of the bar method:

```
>>> a = Foo()
>>> a.bar()
<__main__.Foo object at 0x179b610>
<bound method Foo.bar of <__main__.Foo object at 0x179b610>>
<__main__.Foo object at 0x179b610>
>>> Foo.bar()
TypeError: unbound method bar() must be called with Foo instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
>>> Foo.bar(a)
<__main__.Foo object at 0x179b610>
<bound method Foo.bar of <__main__.Foo object at 0x179b610>>
<__main__.Foo object at 0x179b610>
```

Bringing all the above together, we can define a class as follows:

```
class MyFoo(object):
    a = 10
    def bar(self):
        print self.a
```

This generates a class with 2 attributes: `a` (which is an integer of value 10) and `bar`, which is an unbound method. We can see that `MyFoo.a` is just 10.

We can create extra attributes at run time, both within the class methods, and outside. Consider the following:

```
class MyFoo(object):
    a = 10

    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 20

    def bar(self):
        print self.a
        print self.b

    def eep(self):
        print self.c
```

`__init__` is just the method that is called immediately after an object has been created from a class.

```
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.bar()
10
20
>>> foo.eep()
AttributeError: 'MyFoo' object has no attribute 'c'
>>> foo.c = 30
>>> foo.eep()
30
```

This example shows 2 ways of adding an attribute to a class instance at run time (that is, after the object has been created from it's class).

I hope you can see then, that TestCase and TestSuite are just classes that are used to create test objects. There's nothing special about them except that they happen to have some useful features for writing tests. You can subclass and overwrite them to your heart's content!

Regarding your specific point, both methods and functions can return anything they want.

Your description of module, package and suite seems pretty sound. Note that modules are also objects!