# What are the actions made by the interpreter when an object is instantiated?

Tags: python

I would like to know which is the order of all the actions made by the interpreter behind the scenes (no matter if they are explicitly declared or not).

For example:

- `__init__` call
- `super()` call
- `__new__` call
- global variables
- initialization of constructor variables
- decorators calls etc.

EDIT: let's assume it's a class which has it all (you name it)

```
global_var = 2468
class A(superA):
    class_var = 1234

    __init__(self):
        superA.__init__(self)
        another_var = 5678

    @random_decorator
    def method(self):
        # do stuff
```

Comment: Most of the stuff you list is 100% dependent on your actual code. `__new__` and `__init__` are called; either of these may or may not have `super` calls, variables, decorators, etc.

Comment: It seems like a question like this is usually born out of a desire to understand something in your *code* which isn't behaving the way you want it to ... If that's the case, you could provide a few more details about what you're seeing and what you expect (an actual code example would be great to illustrate the problem too) that could help to understand what you're having trouble with.

Comment: @mgilson It's true, it comes from this question I asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838114/how-to-initialize-global-variable-at-each-class-invocation  in the end it turned out to be a timing problem and that I did not know how the order of class initializations

Comment: the decorator thing does make sense actually. think of it this way: the decorators are called as a part of putting the class itself, together. then once the class is put together, calling it calls its methods.

Comment: Never edit your answer into your question. Please post it as a separate answer, but only if it provides additional info over the other answers. Then accept the best one (which might be yours).

Answer (score 4):

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

>>> foo = Foo(a, b=c)
```

1. It's call `type.__call__(Foo, a, b=c)`... *(instead `type` can be metaclass of your class)*
2. ...which call `Foo.__new__(a, b=c)` which create instance of `Foo`...
3. ...and call `foo.__init__(a, b=c)` and return `foo`.

In other word, `b = B(*args)` works like `type.__call__(B, *args)` where `type.__call__` can be expressed as:

```
class type(object):

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
         obj = cls.__new__(*args, **kwargs)
         obj.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         return obj
```

Function `super` is executed just in the place where you call it (like a normal function).

Decoration is performed in the initialization of classes and methods, replacing them on the wrappers.

Full example:

```
def dec(func):
    print 'decorate', func.__name__
    def wrapper(*args):
        print 'call wrapper of', func.__name__
        return func(*args)
    return wrapper

class A(object):

    def __new__(*args):
        print 'call A.__new__'
        return object.__new__(*args)

    def __init__(self, *args):
        print 'call A.__init__'


class MyMetaclass(type):

    def __call__(mcls, *args):
        print 'call MyMetaclass.__call__'
        return super(MyMetaclass, mcls).__call__(*args)

class B(A):

    __metaclass__ = MyMetaclass

    @dec
    def __new__(*args):
        print 'call B.__new__'
        return A.__new__(*args)

    @dec
    def __init__(self, *args):
        print 'call B.__init__'
        return super(B, self).__init__(*args)

print 'start creating instance'
b = B()
print 'end creating instance'
```

Result:

```
decorate __new__
decorate __init__
start creating instance
call MyMetaclass.__call__
call wrapper of __new__
call B.__new__
call A.__new__
call wrapper of __init__
call B.__init__
call A.__init__
end creating instance
```

Answer (score 2):

It's all rather straightforward. When a module is loaded, code is run from the top to the bottom. Global variables will thus be instantiated as they appear in the module code. When a function is called, the code in it runs from top to bottom.

Decorators are somewhat of an exception in that they are called after the function they are decorating has been defined, in bottom to top order. So if you have:

```
@hits
@dies
@rofls
def watcher(): pass
```

it's the same as:

```
def watcher(): pass
watcher = hits(dies(rofls(watcher)))
```

This makes sense if you think of each decorator wrapping everything below it.

When an object is created, first `__new__` is called, then `__init__`. `super()` is called if you happen to have a call to it somewhere, much like anything else... 'constructor variables' are just initialized whenever you happen to have variable assignment in an `__init__`.

EDIT: To look at your example:

```
class A(superA):
    class_var = 1234

    def __init__(self):
        superA.__init__(self)
        another_var = 5678

    @random_decorator
    def method(self):
        # do stuff
```

I will instead teach you how to fish.

```
def random_decorator(f):
    print "random_decorator called"
    return f

def init_var(varname, val):
    print '%s being initialized' % (varname,)
    return val

class superA(object):
    def __new__(cls):
        print 'superA.__new__ called'
        return super(superA, cls).__new__(cls)
    def __init__(self): 
        print "superA.__init__ called"

class A(superA):
    class_var = init_var('class_var', 1234)

    def __new__(cls):
        print 'A.__new__ called'
        return super(A, cls).__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self):
        print 'A.__init__ called'
        superA.__init__(self)
        another_var = init_var('another_var', 5678)

    @random_decorator
    def method(self):
        print 'method called'
        # do stuff

    class_var2 = init_var('class_var2', 9012)

A().method()
```

See what order the print statements come out in.