# Tkinter menu command action carried out before calling, Why?

Tags: python, menu, tkinter, static-methods

The following is producing a Tkinter menu with one label "do something". Running the script produces the "done" output immediately, which means before even clicking on the "do something" menu label. Why is that? Am I doing something wrong about the @staticmethod?
Thanks in anticipation.

```
import Tkinter

class AppMenu(object):

  def __init__(self, master):
    self.master = master
    self.file_content = "initialised"
    self.menu_bar(self.file_content)

  def menu_bar(self, file_content):
    menu_bar = Tkinter.Menu(self.master)
    self.menu_bar = Tkinter.Menu(self.master)
    self.master.config(menu=self.menu_bar)
    self.task_menu = Tkinter.Menu(self.menu_bar, tearoff = False)
    self.task_menu.add_command(label = "do something", command = Convert.do(self.file_content))
    self.menu_bar.add_cascade(label = "Task", menu = self.task_menu)

class Convert(object):
  @staticmethod
  def do(text):
    print "done"


root = Tkinter.Tk()
Menu = AppMenu(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`command` argument in `add_command` expects function (or something [Callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234/what-is-a-callable-in-python)).
You aren't passing function `Convert.do` to `add_command`, you pass result of calling `Convert.do(self.file_content)` instead of it.
To pass some arguments to `Convert.do` (`self.file_content` in your case) you can use `lambda`:

```
command=lambda self=self: Convert.do(self.file_content)
```