# issue with callable, detects more than __call__

Tags: python

I am testing the simpleTAL templating library which makes use of callable to test if an object passed into the template is a function or not. The definition of callable says that an object is callable if it contains the magic method `__call__`. See also [What is a "callable" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234/what-is-a-callable-in-python).

However, an object created with the following class definition (python 2.7.4)

```
class H:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.a = val
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return 'blah'

h = H(1)
callable(h)
```

will return True. If, however, `__getattr__` raises AttributeError, which does not make sense to do systematically, it will return False!

Can someone shed some light on this issue and possibly a solution? (I don't want h to be callable).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `__getattr__` hook returns a value for **all** attributes:

```
>>> h.__call__
'blah'
```

and thus a test for `hasattr(h, '__call__')` returns `True`:

```
>>> hasattr(h, '__call__')
True
```

Make sure you raise a `AttributeError` for attributes the object doesn't support instead.

Note: this applies *only* to old-style instances; instances for new-style classes (the default in Python 3, and any class inheriting from `object` in Python 2) are not tested for the `__call__` attribute; instead the class itself is consulted.

You could thus switch to new-style classes as well to mitigate this, but your `__getattr__` should still not be too broad.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that new-style classes don't behave this way.

Comment: @user2357112 how do they behave? Could you provide your own answer perhaps? I'm very interested.

Comment: doh!! so a simple solution is to raise AttributeError when name='__call__' !!! Let's hope there are not other traps with implementing __getattr__!!  many thanks!

Comment: @koriander: test for leading underscores perhaps?

Comment: Specifically, `callable` does not call `hasattr` when testing new-style classes.

Comment: OK - so this code will this code return `False` or `True` with a new-style-class?

Comment: @MikeVella: Because `hasattr()` is not used, `callable(h)` will return `False` even though `h.__getattr__('__call__')` returns a value.

Comment: @MikeVella: Instead, dunder methods (double underscore) are looked up directly on the class.

Comment: Martijn, thus a better solution is to use new-style classes?

Comment: @koriander: that could also be a solution, yes. There are many other benefits to using new-style classes, making it the better choice.

Comment: great! perhaps you could add it also to your post. Many thanks again, I struggled with this issue for too long.