# What does "TypeError 'xxx' object is not callable" means?

Tags: python

As a starting developer in Python I've seen this error message many times appearing in my console but I don't fully understand what does it means.

Could anyone tell me, in a general way, what kind of action produces this error?

Comment: If you're dealing with an object that supports indexing, use `x[y]` instead of `x(y)`.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

That error occurs when you try to call, with **`()`**, an object that is not [callable](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__).

A callable object can be a function or a class (that implements `__call__` method). According to [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__):

> **object.__call__(self[, args...])**: Called when the instance is “called” as a function

For example:

```
x = 1
print x()
```

`x` is not a callable object, but you are trying to call it as if it were it. This example produces the error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

---

For better understaing of what is a **callable** object [read this answer in another SO post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/111255/2670792)

Answer (score 16):

The other answers detail the reason for the error. A possible cause (to check) may be your class has a variable and method with the same name, which you then call. Python accesses the variable as a callable - with `()`.

e.g. Class A defines `self.a` and `self.a()`:

```
>>> class A:
...     def __init__(self, val):
...         self.a = val
...     def a(self):
...         return self.a
...
>>> my_a = A(12)
>>> val = my_a.a()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
>>>
```

Answer (score 11):

The action occurs when you attempt to call an object which is not a function, as with `()`. For instance, this will produce the error:

```
>>> a = 5
>>> a()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Class instances can also be called if they define a method `__call__`

One common mistake that causes this error is trying to look up a list or dictionary element, but using parentheses instead of square brackets, i.e. `(0)` instead of `[0]`

Answer (score 3):

The exception is raised when you try to call not callable object. Callable objects are (functions, methods, objects with [`__call__`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__))

```
>>> f = 1
>>> callable(f)
False
>>> f()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this error message through a silly mistake. A classic example of Python giving you plenty of room to make a fool of yourself. Observe:

```
class DOH(object):
    def __init__(self, property=None):
        self.property=property

    def property():
        return property

    x = DOH(1)
    print(x.property())
```

Results

```
$ python3 t.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(x.property())
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

The problem here of course is that the function is overwritten with a property.