# PySpark DataFrame When to use/ not to use Select

Tags: select, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

Based on PySpark document:

> A DataFrame is equivalent to a relational table in Spark SQL, and can be created using various functions in SQLContext

Meaning I can use Select for showing the value of a column, however, I saw sometimes these two equivalent codes are used instead:

```
# df is a sample DataFrame with column a
df.a
# or
df['a']
```

And sometimes when I use select I might get an error instead of them and vice versa sometimes I have to use Select.

For example, this is a DataFrame for finding a dog in a given picture problem:

```
joined_df.printSchema()
root
 |-- folder: string (nullable = true)
 |-- filename: string (nullable = true)
 |-- width: string (nullable = true)
 |-- height: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dog_list: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

If I want to select the dog details and show 10 rows, this code shows an error:

```
print(joined_df.dog_list.show(truncate=False))

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
    print(joined_df.dog_list.show(truncate=False))
TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
```

And this is not:

```
print(joined_df.select('dog_list').show(truncate=False))
```

Question1: When I have to use Select and when I have to use df.a or df["a"]

Question2: what is the meaning of the error above? 'Column' object is not callable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df.col_name` return a Column object but `df.select("col_name")` return another dataframe

see this for [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.select)

The key here is Those two methods are returning two different objects, that is why your `print(joined_df.dog_list.show(truncate=False))` give you the error. Meaning that the Column object does not have this .show method but the dataframe does.

So when you call a function, function takes Column as input, you should use df.col_name, if you want to operate at dataframe level, you want to use df.select("col_name")

Comment: Thank you, then why it shows this error 'Column' object is not callable.? This error is very confusing and we see it in many different situations.

Comment: mostly, it is because the Column object does not have such a method, or the Column object cant not be used in a function call. I agree it is not very intuitive [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21324940/python-what-typeerror-xxx-object-is-not-callable-means) is a general one on python object