# TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable when trying to get dtypes

Tags: python, pandas

I have data organized in the form below 
it represents data, each natural gas well has a column that represents its production rate

whenever I want to see the data types I get this error 
[image]

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: Also, this issue has been covered many times, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21324940/python-what-typeerror-xxx-object-is-not-callable-means.

Answer (score 1):

The series isn't callable because it's an object, not a function, so don't put the `()` on the end of it. Just use:

```
print(OBA_gas.dtypes)
```