# TypeError: 'csr_matrix' object is not callable

Tags: api, machine-learning, flask, deployment

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vAwZ.png)I create a machine learning project and i want to deploy it using flask .
I save `TFIDF` in `vectorizer.pkl` and load it , but when i run my `app.py` , I have got this error:

```
TypeError: 'csr_matrix' object is not callable
```

```
loaded_model= load("model_et.pkl")
loaded_vec = load("vectorizer.pkl")
pstem = PorterStemmer()
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/testcase',methods=['POST','GET'])
def test_case():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        req_json=request.json
        message=req_json['requirement']
        text = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", ' ', message)
        text = text.lower()
        text_vect = loaded_vec.transform([text])
        result = loaded_model.predict([text_vect])
        return result
```

Comment: since you didn't share any code (!), have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21324981/12368419

Comment: i added my code . Check it if you can please

Comment: but there's no reference to `csr_matrix` in your code ! refer to this tuto https://machinelearningmastery.com/sparse-matrices-for-machine-learning/ and this docs https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html

Comment: all i need is to applicate TFIDF that i save to my new text . I don't now why csr_metrix is here