# Unable to compare numeric values in python using function call

Tags: python

I have written the following python code:

```
class Smartphone:
    def __init__(self, price):
        self.price = price

    def price():
        return price


def lowest_price(phones):
    cheapest = phones[0]
    for phone in phones:
        if phone.price() < cheapest.price():
            cheapest = phone
    return cheapest


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p1 = Smartphone(950)
    p2 = Smartphone(1950)
    phones = [p1, p2]
    cheapest = lowest_price(phones)
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 21, in <module>
    cheapest = lowest_price(phones)
  File "test.py", line 12, in lowest_price
    if phone.price() < cheapest.price():
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

What does that mean and how do I resolve it? Also price could be a float too.

Comment: `def price():  return price` is not a correct method definition. It must be `def price(self): return self.price`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "TypeError 'xxx' object is not callable" means?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21324940/what-does-typeerror-xxx-object-is-not-callable-means) Specifically, [wmorrison365's answer](/a/53263527/4518341).

Comment: @DYZ same error even after doing that

Comment: BTW, `lowest_price` can be simplified with `min()`. See [Python min function with a list of objects](/q/6085467/4518341)

Comment: In addition to the duplicate, you also have an attribute `price` defined in the `__init__`, and a method `price`. Methods and attributes cannot have the same name. Getter / setter property (link in previous comment) is a way to address it.

Answer (score -1):

1. Instance methods must have a first parameter `self` (i.e. `def price(self)`)
2. if you want to return a class field you need to use `self` (i.e. `return self.price`)
3. But there is no need to have a getter for `self.price`
4. Python doesn't know if `cheapest.price` is the *method* `price` or the *field* `price` so it uses the field and then you get that an `int` is not a `callable` (method)

Here is fixed code that takes into account all issues with the code

```
class Smartphone:
    def __init__(self, price):
        self.price = price


def lowest_price(phones):
    cheapest = phones[0]
    for phone in phones:
        if phone.price < cheapest.price:
            cheapest = phone
    return cheapest


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p1 = Smartphone(950)
    p2 = Smartphone(1950)
    phones = [p1, p2]
    cheapest = lowest_price(phones)
```

Comment: *"Python doesn't know if `cheapest.price` is the method `price`"* -- Python's not confused. Setting `self.price = price` overrides the method, there's nothing ambiguous about that.

Comment: @wjandrea, that worked.  But does that mean we should not have methods like price() inside out objects? Could there be a way to achieve the result while having the method price()?

Comment: @dnaiel You don't need a method just to get an attribute. See [Aaron Hall's excellent answer here](/a/36943813/4518341)

Comment: @dnaiel yes you can have price method if you rename the variable self.price as self._price  This is common in Python to name private like variables with a leading underscore.